# Activity indicator in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

Trying to add a full screen activity indicator in SwiftUI.

I can use `.overlay(overlay: )` function in `View` Protocol.

With this, I can make any view overlay, but I can't find the iOS default style `UIActivityIndicatorView` equivalent in `SwiftUI`.

How can I make a default style spinner with `SwiftUI`?

**NOTE:** This is not about adding activity indicator in UIKit framework.

Comment: I tried to find it also, and failed, guess it will be added later :)

Comment: Make sure to file a feedback issue with Apple using the Feedback Assistant. Getting requests in early during the beta process is the best way to see what you want in the framework.

Comment: You can find a [Fully customizable Native Standard version here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59056440/5623035)

Answer (score 462, accepted):

As of **Xcode 12 beta** (**iOS 14**), a new view called `ProgressView` is [available to developers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/progressview?changes=latest_major), and that can display both determinate and indeterminate progress.

Its style defaults to `CircularProgressViewStyle`, which is exactly what we're looking for.

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        ProgressView()
           // and if you want to be explicit / future-proof...
           // .progressViewStyle(CircularProgressViewStyle())
    }
}
```

---

**Xcode 11.x**

Quite a few views are not yet represented in `SwiftUI`, but it's easily to port them into the system.
You need to wrap `UIActivityIndicator` and make it `UIViewRepresentable`.

(More about this can be found in the excellent WWDC 2019 talk - [Integrating SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc19/231))

```swift
struct ActivityIndicator: UIViewRepresentable {

    @Binding var isAnimating: Bool
    let style: UIActivityIndicatorView.Style

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<ActivityIndicator>) -> UIActivityIndicatorView {
        return UIActivityIndicatorView(style: style)
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIActivityIndicatorView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<ActivityIndicator>) {
        isAnimating ? uiView.startAnimating() : uiView.stopAnimating()
    }
}
```

Then you can use it as follows - here's an example of a loading overlay.

Note: I prefer using `ZStack`, rather than `overlay(:_)`, so I know exactly what's going on in my implementation.

```swift
struct LoadingView<Content>: View where Content: View {

    @Binding var isShowing: Bool
    var content: () -> Content

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack(alignment: .center) {

                self.content()
                    .disabled(self.isShowing)
                    .blur(radius: self.isShowing ? 3 : 0)

                VStack {
                    Text("Loading...")
                    ActivityIndicator(isAnimating: .constant(true), style: .large)
                }
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width / 2,
                       height: geometry.size.height / 5)
                .background(Color.secondary.colorInvert())
                .foregroundColor(Color.primary)
                .cornerRadius(20)
                .opacity(self.isShowing ? 1 : 0)

            }
        }
    }

}
```

To test it, you can use this example code:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        LoadingView(isShowing: .constant(true)) {
            NavigationView {
                List(["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"], id: \.self) { row in
                    Text(row)
                }.navigationBarTitle(Text("A List"), displayMode: .large)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: But how to stop it?

Comment: @Bagusflyer you can interact with the `isAnimating` binding inside `ActivityIndicator`

Comment: Hi @MatteoPacini, Thanks for your answer.
But, can you please help me how can i hide the activity indicator.
Can you please put down the code for this?

Comment: This worked almost great, but when I tap the button, in this case to perform a network operation the button gets stuck in tapped state, everything else works great, the network operation is being executed in a separate thread

Comment: @Annu see https://peacemoon.de/blog/2019/06/10/activity-indicator-with-swiftui/

Comment: @Matteo Pacini please give us more detail of stopping this thing! how to bind it? bind it with what? how?

Comment: @Alfi in his code it says `isShowing: .constant(true)`. That means the indicator is always showing. What you need to do is have an `@State` variable that is true when you want the loading indicator to appear (when the data is loading), and then change that to false when you want the loading indicator to disappear (when the data is done loading). If the variable is called `isDataLoading` for example, you would do `isShowing: $isDataLoading` instead of where Matteo put `isShowing: .constant(true)`.

Comment: There are other ways to do it too (like making a custom binding that checks other conditions), but the scenario I mentioned above is the easiest to explain and most likely to occur.

Comment: @MatteoPacini you do not actually need a Binding for this as it is not being modified inside ActivityIndicator or in LoadingView. Just a regular boolean variable works. Binding is useful for when you want to modify the variable inside the view and pass that change back out to the parent.

Comment: Do you know why tintColor has no effect with this implementation of ActivityIndicator ? 
When I do ActivityIndicator(isAnimating: .constant(true), style: .large).tintColor(.red), it stay black.

Comment: @nelsonPARRILLA I suspect that `tintColor` only works on pure Swift UI views - not on bridged (`UIViewRepresentable`) ones.

Comment: How can we put a bool in the new `ProgressView`? smth like ProgressView($showing) { Content() }

Comment: `UIViewRepresentable` is. not working for **widget**s

Comment: Great post! In the `ActivityIndicator` you can remove the `return` statement for `makeUIView` so that it uses implicit return for both functions, for code symmetry. I tried to do an edit, but was rejected :(

Comment: @MatteoPacini Hi, how do you pass a dummy value for the content in the preview `LoadingOverlayView(isShowing: .constant(true), content: <#() -> _#>)`?

Comment: @MatteoPacini @nelsonPARRILLA if you adapt `makeUIView` as follows you can color the spinner

`let indicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: style)`
`indicator.color = .orange`
`return indicator`

Comment: You can set @State isShowing  in your view where you are using and toggle when you finished loading.

Answer (score 146):

## iOS 14

it's just a simple view.

```
ProgressView()
```

Currently, it's defaulted to `CircularProgressViewStyle` but you can manually set the style of it by adding the following modifer:

```
.progressViewStyle(CircularProgressViewStyle())
```

Also, the style could be anything that conforms to `ProgressViewStyle`

---

## iOS 13 and above

> Fully customizable Standard `UIActivityIndicator` in SwiftUI: (Exactly as a native `View`):

You can build and configure it (as much as you could in the original `UIKit`):

```
ActivityIndicator(isAnimating: loading)
    .configure { $0.color = .yellow } // Optional configurations ( bouns)
    .background(Color.blue)
```

[image: Result]

---

#### Just implement this base `struct` and you will be good to go:

```
struct ActivityIndicator: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    typealias UIView = UIActivityIndicatorView
    var isAnimating: Bool
    fileprivate var configuration = { (indicator: UIView) in }

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<Self>) -> UIView { UIView() }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<Self>) {
        isAnimating ? uiView.startAnimating() : uiView.stopAnimating()
        configuration(uiView)
    }
}
```

---

#### Bouns Extension:

With this little helpful extension, you can access the configuration through a `modifier` like other SwiftUI `view`s:

```
extension View where Self == ActivityIndicator {
    func configure(_ configuration: @escaping (Self.UIView)->Void) -> Self {
        Self.init(isAnimating: self.isAnimating, configuration: configuration)
    }
}
```

---

#### The classic way:

Also you can configure the view in a classic initializer:

```
ActivityIndicator(isAnimating: loading) { 
    $0.color = .red
    $0.hidesWhenStopped = false
    //Any other UIActivityIndicatorView property you like
}
```

---

This method is fully adaptable. For example, you can see [How to make TextField become the first responder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59059359/5623035) with the same method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59059359/5623035)

Comment: How to change color of ProgressView?

Comment: ```.progressViewStyle(CircularProgressViewStyle(tint: Color.red))``` will change the color

Comment: Your "Bonus Extension: configure()" calls init for the second time, taking up memory. Am I right? or is it so highly optimized that we are allowed to do such a chain invocation of init?

Comment: It’s a sugar, this is not very expensive for this case but i didn’t measure the performance hit for big views. You can measure and change the implementation to something more efficient (since it is a class) but initializing a struct is not that much expensive to be worried about

Answer (score 108):

If you want to a **swift-ui-style** solution, then this is the magic:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct ActivityIndicator: View {
    
    @State private var isAnimating: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { (geometry: GeometryProxy) in
            ForEach(0..<5) { index in
                Group {
                    Circle()
                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width / 5, height: geometry.size.height / 5)
                        .scaleEffect(calcScale(index: index))
                        .offset(y: calcYOffset(geometry))
                }.frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
                    .rotationEffect(!self.isAnimating ? .degrees(0) : .degrees(360))
                    .animation(Animation
                                .timingCurve(0.5, 0.15 + Double(index) / 5, 0.25, 1, duration: 1.5)
                                .repeatForever(autoreverses: false))
            }
        }
        .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
        .onAppear {
            self.isAnimating = true
        }
    }
    
    func calcScale(index: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return (!isAnimating ? 1 - CGFloat(Float(index)) / 5 : 0.2 + CGFloat(index) / 5)
    }
    
    func calcYOffset(_ geometry: GeometryProxy) -> CGFloat {
        return geometry.size.width / 10 - geometry.size.height / 2
    }
    
}
```

Simply to use:

```
ActivityIndicator()
.frame(width: 50, height: 50)
```

Hope it helps!

**Example Usage:**

```
ActivityIndicator()
    .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
    .foregroundColor(.orange)
```

[image]

Comment: This helped me so much, thanks a lot! You can define functions to create the Circles and add view modifier for the animations to make it more readable.

Comment: Love this solution!

Comment: how would i remove animation if the isAnimating is a State , may a @Binding instead?

Comment: Error In newest Xcode and Swift: "The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions"

Comment: How to add background view?

Comment: That looks great. Only problem is that the animaiton broken when I present it modally using a `.fullScreenCover` and it's inside a `NavigationView`... Then all the dots fly in from the top left of the screen...

Comment: there is a strange visual effect: instead of the circle animating in the middle of the screen, it starts in the upper-left side of the screen, then animates to the center, back and forth. any solution for this.

Comment: A great solution.  Now there is an apple deprecation, though.  Solved with: ```.animation(
                        Animation
                            .timingCurve(0.5, 0.15 + Double(index) / 5, 0.25, 1, duration: 1.5)
                            .repeatForever(autoreverses: false),
                               value: isAnimating)```

Comment: @Georg I have the same problem with NavigationView. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 35):

## Custom Indicators

Although Apple supports native Activity Indicator now from the SwiftUI 2.0, You can Simply implement your own animations. These are all supported on SwiftUI 1.0. Also it **is** working in widgets.

#### Arcs

```
struct Arcs: View {
    @Binding var isAnimating: Bool
    let count: UInt
    let width: CGFloat
    let spacing: CGFloat

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ForEach(0..<Int(count)) { index in
                item(forIndex: index, in: geometry.size)
                    .rotationEffect(isAnimating ? .degrees(360) : .degrees(0))
                    .animation(
                        Animation.default
                            .speed(Double.random(in: 0.2...0.5))
                            .repeatCount(isAnimating ? .max : 1, autoreverses: false)
                    )
            }
        }
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
    }

    private func item(forIndex index: Int, in geometrySize: CGSize) -> some View {
        Group { () -> Path in
            var p = Path()
            p.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: geometrySize.width/2, y: geometrySize.height/2),
                     radius: geometrySize.width/2 - width/2 - CGFloat(index) * (width + spacing),
                     startAngle: .degrees(0),
                     endAngle: .degrees(Double(Int.random(in: 120...300))),
                     clockwise: true)
            return p.strokedPath(.init(lineWidth: width))
        }
        .frame(width: geometrySize.width, height: geometrySize.height)
    }
}
```

<sub>Demo of different variations</sub>
[image: Arcs]

---

## Bars

```
struct Bars: View {
    @Binding var isAnimating: Bool
    let count: UInt
    let spacing: CGFloat
    let cornerRadius: CGFloat
    let scaleRange: ClosedRange<Double>
    let opacityRange: ClosedRange<Double>

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ForEach(0..<Int(count)) { index in
                item(forIndex: index, in: geometry.size)
            }
        }
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
    }

    private var scale: CGFloat { CGFloat(isAnimating ? scaleRange.lowerBound : scaleRange.upperBound) }
    private var opacity: Double { isAnimating ? opacityRange.lowerBound : opacityRange.upperBound }

    private func size(count: UInt, geometry: CGSize) -> CGFloat {
        (geometry.width/CGFloat(count)) - (spacing-2)
    }

    private func item(forIndex index: Int, in geometrySize: CGSize) -> some View {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: cornerRadius,  style: .continuous)
            .frame(width: size(count: count, geometry: geometrySize), height: geometrySize.height)
            .scaleEffect(x: 1, y: scale, anchor: .center)
            .opacity(opacity)
            .animation(
                Animation
                    .default
                    .repeatCount(isAnimating ? .max : 1, autoreverses: true)
                    .delay(Double(index) / Double(count) / 2)
            )
            .offset(x: CGFloat(index) * (size(count: count, geometry: geometrySize) + spacing))
    }
}
```

<sub>Demo of different variations</sub>
[image: Bars]

---

## Blinkers

```
struct Blinking: View {
    @Binding var isAnimating: Bool
    let count: UInt
    let size: CGFloat

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ForEach(0..<Int(count)) { index in
                item(forIndex: index, in: geometry.size)
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)

            }
        }
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
    }

    private func item(forIndex index: Int, in geometrySize: CGSize) -> some View {
        let angle = 2 * CGFloat.pi / CGFloat(count) * CGFloat(index)
        let x = (geometrySize.width/2 - size/2) * cos(angle)
        let y = (geometrySize.height/2 - size/2) * sin(angle)
        return Circle()
            .frame(width: size, height: size)
            .scaleEffect(isAnimating ? 0.5 : 1)
            .opacity(isAnimating ? 0.25 : 1)
            .animation(
                Animation
                    .default
                    .repeatCount(isAnimating ? .max : 1, autoreverses: true)
                    .delay(Double(index) / Double(count) / 2)
            )
            .offset(x: x, y: y)
    }
}
```

<sub>Demo of different variations</sub>
[image: Blinkers]

---

For the sake of preventing *walls of code*, you can find more elegant indicators in **[this repo hosted on the git](https://github.com/MojtabaHs/ActivityIndicator)**.

<sub>Note that all these animations have a `Binding` that **MUST** toggle to be run.</sub>

Comment: This is great! I've found one bug though - there is a really strange animation for `iActivityIndicator(style: .rotatingShapes(count: 10, size: 15))`

Comment: what is the issue with the `iActivityIndicator().style(.rotatingShapes(count: 10, size: 15))` by the way?  @pawello2222 ?

Comment: If you set the `count` to 5 or less, the animation looks fine (looks similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59171234/8697793)). However, if you set the `count` to 15, the leading dot doesn't stop at the *top* of the circle. It starts doing another cycle, then comes *back* to the top and then starts the cycle again. I'm not sure if it's intended. Tested on simulator only, Xcode 12.0.1.

Comment: Hmmmm. That's because animations are not serialized. I should add a serializing option to the framework for that. Thanks for sharing your opinion.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini how do you toggle the binding to run?

Comment: Just assign it to a bool and a button. There is an issue with SwiftUI animation so you need to wrap it inside another view if you need an autoplay version. I explained in a demo at the repo. @GarySabo

Comment: there is a strange visual effect: instead of the circle animating in the middle of the screen, it starts in the upper-left side of the screen, then animates to the center, back and forth. any solution for this.  @m

Comment: Seems like at least the Bars could use some updates to recent syntax.

Answer (score 14):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var isCircleRotating = true
    @State private var animateStart = false
    @State private var animateEnd = true
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            Circle()
                .stroke(lineWidth: 10)
                .fill(Color.init(red: 0.96, green: 0.96, blue: 0.96))
                .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
            
            Circle()
                .trim(from: animateStart ? 1/3 : 1/9, to: animateEnd ? 2/5 : 1)
                .stroke(lineWidth: 10)
                .rotationEffect(.degrees(isCircleRotating ? 360 : 0))
                .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                .onAppear() {
                    withAnimation(Animation
                                    .linear(duration: 1)
                                    .repeatForever(autoreverses: false)) {
                        self.isCircleRotating.toggle()
                    }
                    withAnimation(Animation
                                    .linear(duration: 1)
                                    .delay(0.5)
                                    .repeatForever(autoreverses: true)) {
                        self.animateStart.toggle()
                    }
                    withAnimation(Animation
                                    .linear(duration: 1)
                                    .delay(1)
                                    .repeatForever(autoreverses: true)) {
                        self.animateEnd.toggle()
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

**Activity indicator in SwiftUI**

```
import SwiftUI

struct Indicator: View {

    @State var animateTrimPath = false
    @State var rotaeInfinity = false

    var body: some View {

        ZStack {
            Color.black
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            ZStack {
                Path { path in
                    path.addLines([
                        .init(x: 2, y: 1),
                        .init(x: 1, y: 0),
                        .init(x: 0, y: 1),
                        .init(x: 1, y: 2),
                        .init(x: 3, y: 0),
                        .init(x: 4, y: 1),
                        .init(x: 3, y: 2),
                        .init(x: 2, y: 1)
                    ])
                }
                .trim(from: animateTrimPath ? 1/0.99 : 0, to: animateTrimPath ? 1/0.99 : 1)
                .scale(50, anchor: .topLeading)
                .stroke(Color.yellow, lineWidth: 20)
                .offset(x: 110, y: 350)
                .animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 1.5).repeatForever(autoreverses: true))
                .onAppear() {
                    self.animateTrimPath.toggle()
                }
            }
            .rotationEffect(.degrees(rotaeInfinity ? 0 : -360))
            .scaleEffect(0.3, anchor: .center)
            .animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 1.5)
            .repeatForever(autoreverses: false))
            .onAppear(){
                self.rotaeInfinity.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Indicator_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Indicator()
    }
}
```

[image: Activity indicator in SwiftUI]

Answer (score 4):

I implemented the classic UIKit indicator using SwiftUI.
[See the activity indicator in action here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/th2Ba.gif)

```
struct ActivityIndicator: View {
  @State private var currentIndex: Int = 0

  func incrementIndex() {
    currentIndex += 1
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(50), execute: {
      self.incrementIndex()
    })
  }

  var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { (geometry: GeometryProxy) in
      ForEach(0..<12) { index in
        Group {
          Rectangle()
            .cornerRadius(geometry.size.width / 5)
            .frame(width: geometry.size.width / 8, height: geometry.size.height / 3)
            .offset(y: geometry.size.width / 2.25)
            .rotationEffect(.degrees(Double(-360 * index / 12)))
            .opacity(self.setOpacity(for: index))
        }.frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
      }
    }
    .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
    .onAppear {
      self.incrementIndex()
    }
  }

  func setOpacity(for index: Int) -> Double {
    let opacityOffset = Double((index + currentIndex - 1) % 11 ) / 12 * 0.9
    return 0.1 + opacityOffset
  }
}

struct ActivityIndicator_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    ActivityIndicator()
      .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
      .foregroundColor(.blue)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A convenient way in `SwiftUI` that I found useful is 2 step approach:

1. Create a `ViewModifier` that will embed your view into `ZStack` and add progress indicator on top. Could be something like this:

   ```
    struct LoadingIndicator: ViewModifier {
    let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.3
    let height =  UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.3

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        return ZStack {
            content
                .disabled(true)
                .blur(radius: 2)

            //gray background
            VStack{}
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
                .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
                .cornerRadius(20)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

            //progress indicator
            ProgressView()
                .frame(width: width, height: height)
                .background(Color.white)
                .cornerRadius(20)
                .opacity(1)
                .shadow(color: Color.gray.opacity(0.5), radius: 4.0, x: 1.0, y: 2.0)
          }
   }
   ```
2. Create view extension that will make conditional modifier application available to any view:

   ```
    extension View {
    /// Applies the given transform if the given condition evaluates to `true`.
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - condition: The condition to evaluate.
    ///   - transform: The transform to apply to the source `View`.
    /// - Returns: Either the original `View` or the modified `View` if the condition is `true`.
    @ViewBuilder func `if`<Content: View>(_ condition: Bool, transform: (Self) -> Content) -> some View {
        if condition {
            transform(self)
        } else {
            self
        }
      }
   }
   ```
3. Usage is very intuitive. Suppose that `myView()` returns whatever your view is. You just conditionally apply the modifier using `.if` view extension from step 2:

   ```
    var body: some View {
        myView()
          .if(myViewModel.isLoading){ view in
            view.modifier(LoadingIndicator())
        }
    }
   ```

In case that `myViewModel.isLoading` is false, no modifier will be applied, so loading indicator won't show.

Of course, you can use any kind of progress indicator you wish - default or your own custom one.

Answer (score 4):

*Activity Indicator or Loader*

[image]

```
struct LoaderView: View {
    
 @State var isAnimating = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Circle()
                .trim(from: 0, to: 0.7)
                .stroke(Color("Blue"), lineWidth: 4)
                .frame(width: 80, height: 80)
                .rotationEffect(.degrees(isAnimating ? 360 : 0))
                .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                .onAppear() {
                    withAnimation(Animation
                                    .linear(duration: 1)
                                    .repeatForever(autoreverses: false)) {
                        self.isAnimating = true
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
struct HomeView: View {

  @State var isShowLoader : Bool = false
  
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
           Button(action: {
                  isShowLoader.toggle()
                   }) {
                   Text("Loader")
                   }
                   .buttonStyle(.plain)
           if isShowLoader {
             LoaderView()
        }
     }
  }
}
```

SwiftUI Activity indicator for macOS and iOS.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to [**Mojatba Hosseini**'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59056440/5623035),

I've made a few updates so that this can be put in a **swift package**:

**Activity indicator:**

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

public struct ActivityIndicator: UIViewRepresentable {

  public typealias UIView = UIActivityIndicatorView
  public var isAnimating: Bool = true
  public var configuration = { (indicator: UIView) in }

 public init(isAnimating: Bool, configuration: ((UIView) -> Void)? = nil) {
    self.isAnimating = isAnimating
    if let configuration = configuration {
        self.configuration = configuration
    }
 }

 public func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<Self>) -> UIView {
    UIView()
 }

 public func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: 
    UIViewRepresentableContext<Self>) {
     isAnimating ? uiView.startAnimating() : uiView.stopAnimating()
     configuration(uiView)
}}
```

**Extension:**

```
public extension View where Self == ActivityIndicator {
func configure(_ configuration: @escaping (Self.UIView) -> Void) -> Self {
    Self.init(isAnimating: self.isAnimating, configuration: configuration)
 }
}
```

Comment: how can i use this?

Answer (score 2):

It's really easy with SwiftUI 2.0 I made this simple and easy custom view with `ProgressView`

Here is how it looks:

[image]

Code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ActivityIndicatorView: View {
    @Binding var isPresented:Bool
    var body: some View {
        if isPresented{
            ZStack{
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15).fill(CustomColor.gray.opacity(0.1))
                ProgressView {
                    Text("Loading...")
                        .font(.title2)
                }
            }.frame(width: 120, height: 120, alignment: .center)
            .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25).stroke(CustomColor.gray,lineWidth: 2))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have modified Matteo Pacini's Answer for macOS using AppKit and SwiftUI. This allows you to use NSProgressIndicator in SwiftUI while retaining capability for macOS 10.15.

```
import AppKit
import SwiftUI

struct ActivityIndicator: NSViewRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var isAnimating: Bool
    let style: NSProgressIndicator.Style

    func makeNSView(context: NSViewRepresentableContext<ActivityIndicator>) -> NSProgressIndicator {
        let progressIndicator = NSProgressIndicator()
        progressIndicator.style = self.style
        return progressIndicator
    }

    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSProgressIndicator, context: NSViewRepresentableContext<ActivityIndicator>) {
        isAnimating ? nsView.startAnimation(nil) : nsView.stopAnimation(nil)
    }
    
}
```

Usage is as follows:

```
ActivityIndicator(isAnimating: .constant(true), style: .spinning)
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Try this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct LoadingPlaceholder: View {
    var text = "Loading..."
    init(text:String ) {
        self.text = text
    }
    var body: some View {
        VStack(content: {
            ProgressView(self.text)
        })
    }
}
```

More information about at  SwiftUI [ProgressView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/progressview)

Answer (score 1):

my 2 cents for nice and simpler code of batuhankrbb, showing use of isPresented in timer... or other stuff... (I will use it in url callback..)

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//
//  Created by ing.conti on 27/01/21.


import SwiftUI

struct ActivityIndicatorView: View {
    @Binding var isPresented:Bool
    var body: some View {
        if isPresented{
            ZStack{
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15).fill(Color.gray.opacity(0.1))
                ProgressView {
                    Text("Loading...")
                        .font(.title2)
                }
            }.frame(width: 120, height: 120, alignment: .center)
            .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25).stroke(Color.gray,lineWidth: 2))
        }
    }
}



struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isPresented = false
    @State var counter = 0
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack{
            Text("Hello, world! \(counter)")
                .padding()
            
            ActivityIndicatorView(isPresented: $isPresented)
        }.onAppear(perform: {
            _ = startRefreshing()
        })
    }
    
    
    
    func startRefreshing()->Timer{
        
        let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { timer in
            
            counter+=1
            print(counter)
            if counter>2{
                isPresented = true
            }
            
            if counter>4{
                isPresented = false
                timer.invalidate()
            }
        }
        return timer
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Activity View

struct ActivityIndicator: UIViewRepresentable {

    let style: UIActivityIndicatorView.Style
    @Binding var animate: Bool

    private let spinner: UIActivityIndicatorView = {
        $0.hidesWhenStopped = true
        return $0
    }(UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .medium))

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<ActivityIndicator>) -> UIActivityIndicatorView {
        spinner.style = style
        return spinner
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIActivityIndicatorView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<ActivityIndicator>) {
        animate ? uiView.startAnimating() : uiView.stopAnimating()
    }

    func configure(_ indicator: (UIActivityIndicatorView) -> Void) -> some View {
        indicator(spinner)
        return self
    }   
}

// Usage
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var animate = false

    var body: some View {
            ActivityIndicator(style: .large, animate: $animate)
                .configure {
                    $0.color = .red
            }
            .background(Color.blue)
    }
}
```