# SwiftUI: How to make TextField become first responder?

Tags: swift, textfield, swiftui, first-responder

Here's my `SwiftUI` code:

```
struct ContentView : View {

    @State var showingTextField = false
    @State var text = ""

    var body: some View {
        return VStack {
            if showingTextField {
                TextField($text)
            }
            Button(action: { self.showingTextField.toggle() }) {
                Text ("Show")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I want is when the text field becomes *visible*, to make the text field become the first responder (i.e. receive focus & have the keyboard pop up).

Comment: The fact that something basic like this isn't even supported shows how immature SwiftUI is at the moment. Look at the solutions below, it's ridiculous for something that is supposed to make GUI coding "simpler"

Answer (score 38, accepted):

## iOS 15.0+

macOS 12.0+,

Mac Catalyst 15.0+,

tvOS 15.0+,

watchOS 8.0+

### Use `focused(_:)` if you have a single TextField.

> focused(_:)
>
> Modifies this view by binding its focus state to the given **Boolean** state value.

```
struct NameForm: View {
    
    @FocusState private var isFocused: Bool
    
    @State private var name = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Name", text: $name)
            .focused($isFocused)
        
        Button("Submit") {
            if name.isEmpty {
                isFocued = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Use `focused(_:equals:)` should you have multiple TextFields.

> focused(_:equals:)
>
> Modifies this view by binding its focus state to the given state value.

```
struct LoginForm: View {
    enum Field: Hashable {
        case usernameField
        case passwordField
    }

    @State private var username = ""
    @State private var password = ""
    @FocusState private var focusedField: Field?

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            TextField("Username", text: $username)
                .focused($focusedField, equals: .usernameField)

            SecureField("Password", text: $password)
                .focused($focusedField, equals: .passwordField)

            Button("Sign In") {
                if username.isEmpty {
                    focusedField = .usernameField
                } else if password.isEmpty {
                    focusedField = .passwordField
                } else {
                    handleLogin(username, password)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### SwiftUI  Documentation

- [focused(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/link/focused(_:)?changes=latest_minor)
- [focused(_:equals:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/foreach/focused(_:equals:))
- [@FocusState](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/focusstate?changes=latest_minor)

---

#### Update

I tested this in `Xcode version 13.0 beta 5 (13A5212g)`. It works

Comment: If only this was backwards compatible. At least to iOS 14!

Comment: focused inside a Form is not working for me

Comment: There is a bug in iOS 15 or Xcode 13. @Dasoga

Comment: Maybe I'm just being dense here, but this seems to be an answer for how to figure out which field is focused, not to SET focus on a field. I'm struggling to figure out how you give a field default focus.

Comment: If the field is inside a `ToolbarItem`, `focused` doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Not Working, I have a TextField inside LazyVStack

Comment: Thanks!!! this answer should be on top!

Answer (score 105):

Using [SwiftUI-Introspect](https://github.com/timbersoftware/SwiftUI-Introspect), you can do:

```swift
TextField("", text: $value)
.introspectTextField { textField in
    textField.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Good to know that it works also with SecureField().

Comment: This Cocoapod worked for me too. I suspect the only reason this wasn't the accepted answer is that this question was asked and answered in June (WWDC19) long before SwiftUI-Introspect was created (late November 2019).

Comment: This introspector pod is awesome, works perfectly in real phone, however in simulator whole view will lose responding if it contains a textfield which requires to be first responder.

Comment: If you have style modifiers on the TextField, you often have to add the introspectTextField modifier after the styles, as the order is important.

Comment: If I have two text fields and I do it like this then everything is cool until I tap into the second text field. As soon as I tap a keyboard button the respective character is added in the first text field that I have made the first responder.

Comment: I noticed the same problem as Schnodderbalken

Comment: @Schnodderbalken The order of the modifiers is VERY important.  For example, if you have .padding(.all), try moving the .introspectTextField { tf in tf.becomeFirstResponder() } up before the .padding(.all).  If you have issues, let me know.

Comment: @Schnodderbalken Also, there may be a bug introduced in the latest release 0.1.0.  Try using the previous release, 0.6.0.  https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect/issues/19#issue-585409519

Comment: Sorry 0.0.6 is the version not 0.6.0.  Don't forget to clean the project.

Comment: It works great for English. However, it refreshes every single type for other languages that requires user to select a word from keyboard. For example, in Chinese, the word picker flash every time you type a new character. Could you please check what went wrong? Thanks

Comment: Works perfectly on macOS. By far the cleanest answer so far...

Comment: I couldn't get this to work on Introspect 0.0.6 nor 0.1.0. :(

Comment: This works for me, but only with one field. If the view is refreshed, it will focus again. It can be overcome with setting a state variable firstTime or something, so it will not come again.

Comment: Works fine for macOS and iOS.

Comment: I'm trying to use this (0.1.3) inside a [PartialSheet](https://github.com/AndreaMiotto/PartialSheet), and it's not working for me on 14.7.1 device, regardless of what ordering I use for the modifiers.

Comment: It works only with calling becomeFirstResponder in DispatchQueue.main.async with after 1 sec.

Comment: In my use case, the .focused doesn't work, and this does

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me.

Comment: Works for me with Introspect 0.1.4, in Xcode 13/iOS 15.5, on a TextField. If this doesn't work for you, and your use case is to focus a text field when a view appears, consider the `asyncAfter` hack from this thread as an alternative: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/681962.

Answer (score 99):

**Swift UI 3**

As of Xcode 13, you can use the `focused` modifier to make a view become first responder.

---

**Swift UI 1/2**

It doesn't seem to be possible at the moment, but you can implement something similar yourself.

You can create a custom text field and add a value to make it become first responder.

```swift
struct CustomTextField: UIViewRepresentable {

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {

        @Binding var text: String
        var didBecomeFirstResponder = false

        init(text: Binding<String>) {
            _text = text
        }

        func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField) {
            text = textField.text ?? ""
        }

    }

    @Binding var text: String
    var isFirstResponder: Bool = false

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<CustomTextField>) -> UITextField {
        let textField = UITextField(frame: .zero)
        textField.delegate = context.coordinator
        return textField
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> CustomTextField.Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(text: $text)
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<CustomTextField>) {
        uiView.text = text
        if isFirstResponder && !context.coordinator.didBecomeFirstResponder  {
            uiView.becomeFirstResponder()
            context.coordinator.didBecomeFirstResponder = true
        }
    }
}
```

Note: `didBecomeFirstResponder` is needed to make sure the text field becomes first responder only once, not on every refresh by `SwiftUI`!

You would use it like this...

```swift
struct ContentView : View {

    @State var text: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        CustomTextField(text: $text, isFirstResponder: true)
            .frame(width: 300, height: 50)
            .background(Color.red)
    }

}
```

P.S. I added a `frame` as it doesn't behave like the stock `TextField`, meaning there's more stuff going on behind the scenes.

More on `Coordinators` in this excellent WWDC 19 talk:
[Integrating SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc19/231)

**Tested on Xcode 11.4**

Comment: @MatteoPacini this doesn't seem to work on Mac, do you know if there's any solution that works?

Comment: @kipelovets it works when you click any element inside your active view first before launching a modal containing this custom textfield.

Comment: I just ran into this issue where calling `textfield.becomeFirstResponder()` inside of `override func layoutSubviews` caused my app to enter an infinite loop. This happened when I was trying to push on a new ViewController that also had a textView trying to becomFirstResponder inside layoutSubviews. Definitely a sneaky bug to be aware of!

Comment: @matteo What about if you wanted to have the focus/keyboard tab to the next textfield on the return key press on the keyboard. See the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60693733/tab-to-next-text-field-when-next-return-key-hit-on-keyboard-in-swiftui

Comment: @Matteo is this still needed?  Wondering if there is SwiftUI support for programmatically setting focus to a particular TextField yet?

Comment: @Greg Yes, still needed.

Comment: @kipelovets in my case I'm doing an IOS app

Comment: Can also confirm this crashes on copy-paste use in a SwiftUI app on Xcode 11.4

Comment: @ZackShapiro could you please post some test code to look at? I tried copy-pasting on 11.4 and it doesn't crash.

Comment: I tried this and got an "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints." runtime error.

Comment: Seems like adding `.scaleToFit()` resolves the problem with the frame in some cases. No need to specify height and width by yourself. `.scaleToFit()` makes it behave as a `TextField` would. For me it works if the `CustomTextField` is itself wrapped inside another `View`

Comment: @Matteo Pacini, I am trying to use your answer in my code, but I need to call onCommit: {...} for my CustomTextField. How would you handle that?

Comment: Adding `.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)` helped me to make it look like native TextField.

Comment: I assume `_text` (in the Coordinator initializer) should be `self.text`, the @Binding?

Comment: You should add that `focused` only works on iOS 15.0+ ....

Comment: This one is crashing on iOS 13. You need to check if uiView.windows is not nil

Answer (score 96):

## iOS 15

There is a new wrapper called `@FocusState` that controls the state of the keyboard and the focused keyboard ('aka' firstResponder).

> ⚠️ Note that if you want to make it focused at the initial time, you MUST apply a delay. It's a known bug of the SwiftUI.

#### Become First Responder ( Focused )

If you use a `focused` modifier on the text fields, you can make them become focused:

[image: Demo]

#### Resign first responder ( Dismiss keyboard )

or dismiss the keyboard by setting the variable to `nil`:

[image: Demo]

---

#### iOS 13 and above: Old but working!

## Simple wrapper struct - Works like a native:

<sub>**Note that** Text binding support added as requested in the comments</sub>

```
struct LegacyTextField: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding public var isFirstResponder: Bool
    @Binding public var text: String

    public var configuration = { (view: UITextField) in }

    public init(text: Binding<String>, isFirstResponder: Binding<Bool>, configuration: @escaping (UITextField) -> () = { _ in }) {
        self.configuration = configuration
        self._text = text
        self._isFirstResponder = isFirstResponder
    }

    public func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextField {
        let view = UITextField()
        view.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
        view.addTarget(context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.textViewDidChange), for: .editingChanged)
        view.delegate = context.coordinator
        return view
    }

    public func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: Context) {
        uiView.text = text
        configuration(uiView)
        switch isFirstResponder {
        case true: uiView.becomeFirstResponder()
        case false: uiView.resignFirstResponder()
        }
    }

    public func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator($text, isFirstResponder: $isFirstResponder)
    }

    public class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
        var text: Binding<String>
        var isFirstResponder: Binding<Bool>

        init(_ text: Binding<String>, isFirstResponder: Binding<Bool>) {
            self.text = text
            self.isFirstResponder = isFirstResponder
        }

        @objc public func textViewDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
            self.text.wrappedValue = textField.text ?? ""
        }

        public func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
            self.isFirstResponder.wrappedValue = true
        }

        public func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
            self.isFirstResponder.wrappedValue = false
        }
    }
}
```

## Usage:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text = ""
    @State var isFirstResponder = false

    var body: some View {
        LegacyTextField(text: $text, isFirstResponder: $isFirstResponder)
    }
}
```

## Bonus: Completely customizable

```
LegacyTextField(text: $text, isFirstResponder: $isFirstResponder) {
    $0.textColor = .red
    $0.tintColor = .blue
}
```

---

This method is fully adaptable. For example, you can see [**How to add an Activity indicator in SwiftUI**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59056440/5623035) with the same method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59056440/5623035)

Comment: 'ResponderTextField.Type' is not convertible to '(Bool, escaping (ResponderTextField.TheUIView) -> ()) -> ResponderTextField' (aka '(Bool, escaping (UITextField) -> ()) -> ResponderTextField')

Comment: Where did you get that?

Comment: This is missing the $text binding (and label) that TextField usually has? (I couldn't get it to work, anyway)

Comment: Where is the textfield?

Comment: @drtofu I've added binding text support.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini  There are two problems with this. 1. If you write a long sentence, the whole views moves to the left chracter by character as you type in. 2. Configuration does not work. TextColor is stil black.

Comment: @mahan for configuration part. Add `configuration(uiView)` in func updateUIView(_ uiView:context:)

Comment: I really love this solution because it's both versatile and educational for ppl with SwiftUI background. Just one question: What does this do "view.addTarget(context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.textViewDidChange), for: .editingChanged)"?

Comment: This is by far the best answer IMO, and ensures the call site is clean and understandable, it's also closest to Apple's solution in iOS 15.

Comment: This doesn't render properly when displayed inside a `Form` element, it loses the leading offset.

Comment: The problem with .focused() is that it cannot bind to values in an ObservableObject (eg a view model), FocusState is only allowed in a view. So for UI where you have lots of interacting views and logic split out into a view model, you then need to somehow bind your view model to the FocusState.

Comment: @mahan I updated the answer by adding `view.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)`. It fixes the width expansion.

Comment: I think binding is not working sometimes in my Xocde 13.3 and simulator 15.6

Comment: If anybody see UI improper just add ` DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+0.05) {/code/}` for `updateUIView` func

Comment: still Binding not working after adding DispatchQueue

Comment: The LegacyTextField is working great, better than the SwiftUI variant. Thanks!

Answer (score 25):

For anyone who ended up here but faced crashed using @Matteo Pacini's answer, please be aware of this change in beta 4: [Cannot assign to property: '$text' is immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57178382/cannot-assign-to-property-text-is-immutable/57179008#57179008) about this block:

```swift
init(text: Binding<String>) {
    $text = text
}
```

should use:

```swift
init(text: Binding<String>) {
    _text = text
}
```

---

And if you want to make the textfield become first responder in a `sheet`, please be aware that you cannot call `becomeFirstResponder` until the textfield is shown. In other words, putting @Matteo Pacini's textfield directly in `sheet` content causes crash.

To solve the issue, add an additional check `uiView.window != nil` for textfield's visibility. Only focus after it is in the view hierarchy:

```swift
struct AutoFocusTextField: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var text: String

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<AutoFocusTextField>) -> UITextField {
        let textField = UITextField()
        textField.delegate = context.coordinator
        return textField
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context:
        UIViewRepresentableContext<AutoFocusTextField>) {
        uiView.text = text
        if uiView.window != nil, !uiView.isFirstResponder {
            uiView.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
        var parent: AutoFocusTextField

        init(_ autoFocusTextField: AutoFocusTextField) {
            self.parent = autoFocusTextField
        }

        func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField) {
            parent.text = textField.text ?? ""
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was stuck because I was using the `shouldChangeCharactersIn` UITextField delegate while also updating the text in `updateUIView`. By changing to `textFieldDidChangeSelection` to capture the text in the binding, the custom control works great! Thanks.

Comment: It does indeed crash in `sheet` when trying to focus before the input is show. You solution does not crash but it does not focus either... At least in my tests. Basically, updateUIView is called only once.

Comment: This behaves strange if the parent view of the UITextfield is in a middle of an animation

Comment: This crashes for me if another textfield had focus when the sheet with the `AutoFocusTextField` was presented. I had to wrap the call to `becomeFirstResponder()` in a `DispatchQueue.main.async` block.

Comment: Wrapping in `DispatchQueue.main.async` is definitely not working out for me with transition animation. Say, using NavigationView and going from view 1 to view 2 (where becomeFirstResponder is called), with async, the transition animation is played twice.

Comment: Is there a macOS version of this?

Answer (score 12):

## ResponderChain

I made this small package for **cross-platform first responder handling without subclassing views or making custom ViewRepresentables** in SwiftUI on iOS 13+

https://github.com/Amzd/ResponderChain

### How to apply it to your problem

**SceneDelegate.swift**

```swift
...
// Set the ResponderChain as environmentObject
let rootView = ContentView().environmentObject(ResponderChain(forWindow: window))
...
```

**ContentView.swift**

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var chain: ResponderChain
    @State var showingTextField = false
    @State var text = ""

    var body: some View {
        return VStack {
            if showingTextField {
                TextField($text).responderTag("field1").onAppear {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        chain.firstResponder = "field1"
                    }
                }
            }
            Button(action: { self.showingTextField.toggle() }) {
                Text ("Show")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Most elegant solution I have seen so far. Great support on SwiftUI. Used myself and highly recommend!

Comment: You should mention that this solution includes dependencies on two other packages.

Comment: @GeneLoparco well one of them is Introspect which I would recommend to use in any SwiftUI app anyway and the other is a single file with 50 lines.

Comment: I understand that, but it may be helpful to others to know that your solution is not standalone and that there are other code dependencies.  This does not mean that the solution is good or bad.  It is just useful to know about dependencies, that's all.

Comment: This seems to work nicely except that when I use it on a modal, when I dismiss the modal it crashes with 'Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type ResponderChain found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for ResponderChain may be missing as an ancestor of this view.'

Comment: @SomaMan well that’s because you have to attach environmentObjects to modals again. More detailed explanation: https://medium.com/swlh/swiftui-and-the-missing-environment-object-1a4bf8913ba7

Comment: @CasperZandbergen thanks for that, it works now - I'm pretty new to SwiftUI & there's a lot of stuff which is not particularly intuitive...

Comment: @SomaMan yeah they made environment objects even less intuitive in Xcode 12 sadly

Comment: @CasperZandbergen yeah, coming from far too many years of imperative-style programming, I sadly don't find much of SwiftUI intuitive 

Comment: @CasperZandbergen Is there a complete sample project that shows how to use ResponderChain? I can't even figure out how to initialize it given my project has no SceneDelegate or ApplicationDelegate.

Comment: @SafeFastExpressive the readme has a pretty extensive explanation

Comment: @CasperZandbergen Its very nice but doesn't answer my initialization question. A small sample app that demonstrates it in the latest SwiftUI release would go a long way for new SwiftUI developers like myself. I'm entirely unfamiliar with what SceneDelegate & ApplicationDelegate are since they no longer exist in Apples latest example code. I realize SwiftUI itself is terribly documented, but I think that just makes it even more necessary for libraries to document their usage and assumptions extensively.

Comment: Always returns EmptyView.

Comment: @Lars please open an issue on the github with a bit more info

Comment: Since this solution depends internally on Introspect anyway, for basic use, the [one-line solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59277051/145173) using Introspect directly is a leaner choice.

Comment: @EdwardBrey that solution calls becomeFirstResponder every time SwiftUI recalculates the UI (for example when an ObservedObject or State variable changes in a parent view) so you will get the textfield focusing when you wouldn't expect it

Answer (score 10):

In my case I wanted to focused a textfield just right away I used `.onappear` function

```
struct MyView: View {
    
    @FocusState private var isTitleTextFieldFocused: Bool

    @State private var title = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Title", text: $title)
                .focused($isTitleTextFieldFocused)
            
        }
        .padding()
        .onAppear {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                self.isTitleTextFieldFocused = true
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, is this from a library or what?

Comment: This is a native solution @King

Comment: @King it requires iOS 15

Comment: Other than changing the delay to something like `.now() + 0.02` so the keyboard shows up right away, this answer is the best of the bunch, at least for iOS 15.  Quick & easy, no extensive code or dependencies to add.

Comment: Thanks! I tried to get `onappear` to work for days, but looks like the async did the trick.

Comment: This creates a strange bug for me. Using onAppear plus delay for focusing, sometimes (or if you wait long enough, perhaps) hangs the app and the stacktrace reveals some sort of animation loop.

Answer (score 7):

As others have noted (e.g. [@kipelovets comment on the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56507839/swiftui-how-to-make-textfield-become-first-responder#comment102983802_56508132), e.g. [@Eonil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59758160)), I have also not found any of the accepted solutions to work on macOS. I've had some luck, however, using [NSViewControllerRepresentable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/nsviewcontrollerrepresentable) to get a [NSSearchField](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nssearchfield) to appear as the first responder in a SwiftUI view:

```swift
import Cocoa
import SwiftUI

class FirstResponderNSSearchFieldController: NSViewController {

  @Binding var text: String

  init(text: Binding<String>) {
    self._text = text
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
  }

  required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

  override func loadView() {
    let searchField = NSSearchField()
    searchField.delegate = self
    self.view = searchField
  }

  override func viewDidAppear() {
    self.view.window?.makeFirstResponder(self.view)
  }
}

extension FirstResponderNSSearchFieldController: NSSearchFieldDelegate {

  func controlTextDidChange(_ obj: Notification) {
    if let textField = obj.object as? NSTextField {
      self.text = textField.stringValue
    }
  }
}

struct FirstResponderNSSearchFieldRepresentable: NSViewControllerRepresentable {

  @Binding var text: String

  func makeNSViewController(
    context: NSViewControllerRepresentableContext<FirstResponderNSSearchFieldRepresentable>
  ) -> FirstResponderNSSearchFieldController {
    return FirstResponderNSSearchFieldController(text: $text)
  }

  func updateNSViewController(
    _ nsViewController: FirstResponderNSSearchFieldController,
    context: NSViewControllerRepresentableContext<FirstResponderNSSearchFieldRepresentable>
  ) {
  }
}
```

Sample SwiftUI view:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

  @State private var text: String = ""

  var body: some View {
    FirstResponderNSSearchFieldRepresentable(text: $text)
  }
}
```

Comment: This is great - almost exactly what I was looking for. Now I just have to figure out how to always have it as the first responder.

Comment: Worked really well. Thanks!

Comment: Great idea! Didn't think of NSViewControllerRepresentable. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

To fill in this missing functionality, you may install SwiftUIX using Swift Package Manager:

1. In Xcode, open your project and navigate to File → Swift Packages → Add Package Dependency...
2. Paste the repository URL (https://github.com/SwiftUIX/SwiftUIX) and click Next.
3. For Rules, select Branch (with branch set to master).
4. Click Finish.
5. Open the Project settings, add SwiftUI.framework to the Linked Frameworks and Libraries, set Status to Optional.

More Info:  https://github.com/SwiftUIX/SwiftUIX

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftUIX

struct ContentView : View {

    @State var showingTextField = false
    @State var text = ""

    var body: some View {
        return VStack {
            if showingTextField {
                CocoaTextField("Placeholder text", text: $text)
                    .isFirstResponder(true)
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 48, alignment: .center)
            }
            Button(action: { self.showingTextField.toggle() }) {
                Text ("Show")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**SwiftUI**

```
struct ContentView: View {
enum Field {
    case firstTextfield
    case secondTextfield
    case lastTextfield
}

@State private var firstTextfield = ""
@State private var secondTextfield = ""
@State private var lastTextfield = ""
@FocusState private var focusedField: Field?

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        TextField("Enter anything on first textfield", text: $firstTextfield)
            .focused($focusedField, equals: .firstTextfield)
            .submitLabel(.next)

        TextField("Enter anything on second textfield", text: $secondTextfield)
            .focused($focusedField, equals: .secondTextfield)
            .submitLabel(.next)

        TextField("Enter anything on last textfield", text: $lastTextfield)
            .focused($focusedField, equals: .lastTextfield)
            .submitLabel(.join)
    }
    .onSubmit {
        switch focusedField {
        case .firstTextfield:
            focusedField = .secondTextfield
        case .secondTextfield:
            focusedField = .lastTextfield
        default:
            focusedField = nil
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Description: Add an enum with textfields cases, and a property wrapped in a `@FocusState` with type of that enum. Add `focused(_:equals:)` modifier to have a binding value, equal to the enum cases. Now, you can change the `focusedField` to whichever textfield you want to have cursor on, or resign first responder by assigning nil to focusedField.

Answer (score 3):

Not really an answer, just building on Casper's great solution with a convenient modifier -

```
struct StartInput: ViewModifier {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var chain: ResponderChain
    
    private let tag: String
    
    
    init(tag: String) {
        self.tag = tag
    }
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        
        content.responderTag(tag).onAppear() {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                chain.firstResponder = tag
            }
        }
    }
}


extension TextField {
    
    func startInput(_ tag: String = "field") -> ModifiedContent<TextField<Label>, StartInput> {
        self.modifier(StartInput(tag: tag))
    }
}
```

Just use like -

```
TextField("Enter value:", text: $quantity)
    .startInput()
```

Comment: I would like to upvote this given how clean a solution your modifier is, but needs to document it's dependencies. First, what is Async? Second, if ResponderChain and Introspect are required, show them as imports, and provide their URLs for Swift Package manager. This is already a popular question, Caspers answer may be hard to find after more answers.

Comment: @SafeFastExpressive apologies for the Async.main - that was just a wrapper around DispatchQueue.async.main which I forgot to remove. Re your second point, I don't feel it's my place to point out dependencies of someone else's answer to which I'm referring :)

Comment: You are right. This really isn't an answer - and neither is your comment. I can't figure out how to make this "elegant" answer work without more information.

Answer (score 2):

This is a ViewModifier that works with [introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect). It works for AppKit MacOS, Xcode 11.5

```
    struct SetFirstResponderTextField: ViewModifier {
      @State var isFirstResponderSet = false

      func body(content: Content) -> some View {
         content
            .introspectTextField { textField in
            if self.isFirstResponderSet == false {
               textField.becomeFirstResponder()
               self.isFirstResponderSet = true
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

We have a solution that makes controlling the first responder effortless.

https://github.com/mobilinked/MbSwiftUIFirstResponder

```
TextField("Name", text: $name)
    .firstResponder(id: FirstResponders.name, firstResponder: $firstResponder, resignableUserOperations: .all)

TextEditor(text: $notes)
    .firstResponder(id: FirstResponders.notes, firstResponder: $firstResponder, resignableUserOperations: .all)
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does and how it does it; never just post code on its own.

Comment: This is the best answer - it works like a charm!  Nice work.

Answer (score 2):

I took a little bit different approach - instead of `UIViewRepresentable` based on `UITextField` i made it based on `UIView` and and plug it in SwiftUI view hierarchy with `background` modifier. Inside `UIView` i added logic to find first view that `canBecomeFirstResponder` in subviews and parent views.

```
private struct FocusableUIView: UIViewRepresentable {
    var isFirstResponder: Bool = false

    class Coordinator: NSObject {
        var didBecomeFirstResponder = false
    }

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<FocusableUIView>) -> UIView {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .clear
        return view
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> FocusableUIView.Coordinator {
        return Coordinator()
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<FocusableUIView>) {
        guard uiView.window != nil, isFirstResponder, !context.coordinator.didBecomeFirstResponder else {
            return
        }

        var foundRepsonder: UIView?
        var currentSuperview: UIView? = uiView
        repeat {
            foundRepsonder = currentSuperview?.subviewFirstPossibleResponder
            currentSuperview = currentSuperview?.superview
        } while foundRepsonder == nil && currentSuperview != nil

        guard let responder = foundRepsonder else {
            return
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            responder.becomeFirstResponder()
            context.coordinator.didBecomeFirstResponder = true
        }
    }
}

private extension UIView {
    var subviewFirstPossibleResponder: UIView? {
        guard !canBecomeFirstResponder else { return self }

        for subview in subviews {
            if let firstResponder = subview.subviewFirstPossibleResponder {
                return firstResponder
            }
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

Here is an example how to use it to make TextField to autofocus (+ bonus utilise `@FocusState` new iOS 15 api).

```
extension View {
    @ViewBuilder
    func autofocus() -> some View {
        if #available(iOS 15, *) {
            modifier(AutofocusedViewModifiers.Modern())
        } else {
            modifier(AutofocusedViewModifiers.Legacy())
        }
    }
}

private enum AutofocusedViewModifiers {
    struct Legacy: ViewModifier {
        func body(content: Content) -> some View {
            content
                .background(FocusableUIView(isFirstResponder: isFocused))
                .onAppear {
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                        isFocused = true
                    }
                }
        }

        @State private var isFocused = false
    }

    @available(iOS 15, *)
    struct Modern: ViewModifier {
        func body(content: Content) -> some View {
            content
                .focused($isFocused)
                .onAppear {
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                        isFocused = true
                    }
                }
        }

        @FocusState private var isFocused: Bool
    }
}
```

Content view example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("placeholder", text: $text)
            Text("some text")
        }
        .autofocus()
    }
}
```

Comment: Good. How to handle for Multiple TextFields?, like register form with name, password, email, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Selected answer causes some infinite loop issue with AppKit. I don't know about UIKit case.

To avoid that issue, I recommend just sharing `NSTextField` instance directly.

```
import AppKit
import SwiftUI

struct Sample1: NSViewRepresentable {
    var textField: NSTextField
    func makeNSView(context:NSViewRepresentableContext<Sample1>) -> NSView { textField }
    func updateNSView(_ x:NSView, context:NSViewRepresentableContext<Sample1>) {}
}
```

You can use that like this.

```
let win = NSWindow()
let txt = NSTextField()
win.setIsVisible(true)
win.setContentSize(NSSize(width: 256, height: 256))
win.center()
win.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: Sample1(textField: txt))
win.makeFirstResponder(txt)

let app = NSApplication.shared
app.setActivationPolicy(.regular)
app.run()
```

This breaks pure value semantic, but depending on AppKit means you partially abandon pure value semantic and gonna afford some dirtiness. This is a magic hole we need right now for deal with lack of first-responder control in SwiftUI.

As we access `NSTextField` directly, setting first-responder is plain AppKit way, therefore no visible source of trouble.

You can download working source code [here](https://github.com/eonil/swift-ui-minimal-samples/blob/37057355b34c0d749d264446e3e1d30cc17aac57/Sources/CustomNSViewFirstResponder2/main.swift).

Answer (score 1):

At its **Simplest** **form in** **iOS 13**  ( without using any third party sdk/repo , or if you havent upgraded to iOS 14 to utilise the `focus` modifiers)

```
struct CustomTextField: UIViewRepresentable {
            
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextField {
         UITextField(frame: .zero)
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: Context) {
        uiView.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
struct ContentView : View {

    var body: some View {
        CustomTextField()
            .frame(width: 300, height: 50)
            .background(Color.red)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Responder Chain is not available to be consumed via SwiftUI, so we have to consume it using UIViewRepresentable.

Do have a look at the below link as I have made a workaround that can work similarly to the way we use to do using UIKit.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61121199/6445871

Answer (score 0):

It is my variant of the implementation, based on @Mojtaba Hosseini and @Matteo Pacini solutions.
I am still new to SwiftUI, so I won't guarantee the absolute correctness of the code, but it works.

I hope it would be helpful to someone.

ResponderView: It is a generic-responder view, that could be used with any UIKit view.

```
struct ResponderView<View: UIView>: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var isFirstResponder: Bool
    var configuration = { (view: View) in }

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<Self>) -> View { View() }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator($isFirstResponder)
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: View, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<Self>) {
        context.coordinator.view = uiView
        _ = isFirstResponder ? uiView.becomeFirstResponder() : uiView.resignFirstResponder()
        configuration(uiView)
    }
}

// MARK: - Coordinator
extension ResponderView {
    final class Coordinator {
        @Binding private var isFirstResponder: Bool
        private var anyCancellable: AnyCancellable?
        fileprivate weak var view: UIView?

        init(_ isFirstResponder: Binding<Bool>) {
            _isFirstResponder = isFirstResponder
            self.anyCancellable = Publishers.keyboardHeight.sink(receiveValue: { [weak self] keyboardHeight in
                guard let view = self?.view else { return }
                DispatchQueue.main.async { self?.isFirstResponder = view.isFirstResponder }
            })
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - keyboardHeight
extension Publishers {
    static var keyboardHeight: AnyPublisher<CGFloat, Never> {
        let willShow = NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.keyboardWillShowNotification)
            .map { ($0.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? CGRect)?.height ?? 0 }

        let willHide = NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.keyboardWillHideNotification)
            .map { _ in CGFloat(0) }

        return MergeMany(willShow, willHide)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}

struct ResponderView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ResponderView<UITextField>.init(isFirstResponder: .constant(false)) {
            $0.placeholder = "Placeholder"
        }.previewLayout(.fixed(width: 300, height: 40))
    }
}
```

ResponderTextField - It is a convenient text-field wrapper around ResponderView.

```
struct ResponderTextField: View {
    var placeholder: String
    @Binding var text: String
    @Binding var isFirstResponder: Bool
    private var textFieldDelegate: TextFieldDelegate

    init(_ placeholder: String, text: Binding<String>, isFirstResponder: Binding<Bool>) {
        self.placeholder = placeholder
        self._text = text
        self._isFirstResponder = isFirstResponder
        self.textFieldDelegate = .init(text: text)
    }

    var body: some View {
        ResponderView<UITextField>(isFirstResponder: $isFirstResponder) {
            $0.text = self.text
            $0.placeholder = self.placeholder
            $0.delegate = self.textFieldDelegate
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - TextFieldDelegate
private extension ResponderTextField {
    final class TextFieldDelegate: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
        @Binding private(set) var text: String

        init(text: Binding<String>) {
            _text = text
        }

        func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField) {
            text = textField.text ?? ""
        }
    }
}

struct ResponderTextField_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ResponderTextField("Placeholder",
                           text: .constant(""),
                           isFirstResponder: .constant(false))
            .previewLayout(.fixed(width: 300, height: 40))
    }
}
```

And way to use that.

```
struct SomeView: View {
    @State private var login: String = ""
    @State private var password: String = ""
    @State private var isLoginFocused = false
    @State private var isPasswordFocused = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ResponderTextField("Login", text: $login, isFirstResponder: $isLoginFocused)
            ResponderTextField("Password", text: $password, isFirstResponder: $isPasswordFocused)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can this be modified for use with macOS?

Comment: I will try:) Meanwhile, I guess this https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/125339 may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @JoshuaKifer answer's above, if you're dealing with the navigation animation being glitchy when using Introspect to make a text field first responder. Use this:

```
import SchafKit

@State var field: UITextField?

TextField("", text: $value)
.introspectTextField { textField in
    field = textField
}
.onDidAppear {
     field?.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

More details on this solution [here](https://githubmemory.com/repo/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect/issues/102).

Answer (score 0):

The correct SwiftUI way is to use `@FocusState` as mentioned above. However this API is available only for iOS 15. If you are using iOS 14 or iOS 13 you can use the Focuser library which is modelled to follow Apple API.

https://github.com/art-technologies/swift-focuser

[image]

Here's an example code. You will notice that API looks almost exactly as Apple, however Focuser also offers to use keyboard to move first responder down the chain which is pretty handy.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're having any problem with *@JoshuaKifer* or *@ahaze* 's response,
I've solved mine by **using the modifier on the parent class**, instead of on the TextField itself.

**What I was doing:**

```
TextField("Placeholder text...", text: $searchInput)
    .introspectTextField { textField in
        textField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
```

**How I solved my problem:**

```
   YourParentStruct(searchInput: $searchInput)
       .introspectTextField { textField in
           textField.becomeFirstResponder()
       }
```

I'll put the definition of the parent struct below just for clearness

```
   struct YourParentStruct: View {
       @Binding var searchInput: String

       var body: some View {
           HStack {
               TextField("Placeholder text...", text: $searchInput)                      
                  .padding()
                  .background(Color.gray)
                  .cornerRadius(10)
           }
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know its too late but if it helps anyone this is how I do it.

```
import SwiftUI
import Introspect

struct MyView: View {
    
    @Binding var text1: String
    @Binding var text2: String
    
    @State private var toggleTF: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        
        TextField("TextField 1", text: $text1)
            .introspectTextField{ tF in
                if toggleTF {
                    tF.becomeFirstResponder()
                }
            }
        
        TextField("TextField 2", text: $text1)
            .introspectTextField{ tF in
                if !toggleTF {
                    tF.becomeFirstResponder()
                }
            }
        
        Button("Toggle textfields") {
            toggleTF.toggle()
        }
    }
}
```