# Get mouse/pointer position for tap gestures in SwiftUI for macOS apps

Tags: swiftui, gesture

Currently we can easily track the pointer position inside a view during a drag gesture thanks to `DragGesture` in SwiftUI because this gesture exposes the start position and the translation relative to a given coordinate space:

```swift
struct Example: View {
    @GestureState private var startPosition: CGPoint = .zero
    @GestureState private var translation: CGSize = .zero
    
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.black)
            .frame(width: 600, height: 400)
            .coordinateSpace(name: "rectangle")
            .overlay(coordinates)
            .gesture(dragGesture)
    }
    
    var dragGesture: some Gesture {
        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 5, coordinateSpace: .named("rectangle"))
            .updating($startPosition) { (value, state, _) in
                state = value.startLocation
            }
            .updating($translation) { (value, state, _) in
                state = value.translation
            }
    }
    
    var coordinates: some View {
        Text("\(startPosition.x) \(startPosition.y) \(translation.width) \(translation.height)")
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .font(Font.body.monospacedDigit())
    }
}
```

On the opposite `TapGesture` does not give any information about the position of the tap it only  signals when the tap occurred:

```swift
var tapGesture: some Gesture {
    TapGesture()
        .onEnded { _ in
            print("A tap occurred")
        }
}
```

---

**Is there a simple way to get the pointer location when a tap gesture occurs?**

I found little solutions around the web but they usually require a lot of boilerplate or are not handy.

A wrapper around some UIKit think could do the trick, any idea?

Comment: may be this will be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56513942/how-to-detect-a-tap-gesture-location-in-swiftui

Comment: you can get the tap location with drag Gesture as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update iOS 16

Starting form iOS 16 / macOS 13, the new [`onTapGesture`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/ontapgesture(count:coordinatespace:perform:)) modifier makes available the location of the tap/click in the action closure as a `CGPoint`:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    Rectangle()
      .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
      .onTapGesture { location in 
        print("Tapped at \(location)")
      }
  }
}
```

---

## Original Answer

### Edit

I found a better solution by experimenting with simultaneous gestures. This solution integrated perfectly with SwiftUI gestures and works similarly to other existing gestures:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ClickGesture: Gesture {
    let count: Int
    let coordinateSpace: CoordinateSpace
    
    typealias Value = SimultaneousGesture<TapGesture, DragGesture>.Value
    
    init(count: Int = 1, coordinateSpace: CoordinateSpace = .local) {
        precondition(count > 0, "Count must be greater than or equal to 1.")
        self.count = count
        self.coordinateSpace = coordinateSpace
    }
    
    var body: SimultaneousGesture<TapGesture, DragGesture> {
        SimultaneousGesture(
            TapGesture(count: count),
            DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: coordinateSpace)
        )
    }
    
    func onEnded(perform action: @escaping (CGPoint) -> Void) -> _EndedGesture<ClickGesture> {
        ClickGesture(count: count, coordinateSpace: coordinateSpace)
            .onEnded { (value: Value) -> Void in
                guard value.first != nil else { return }
                guard let location = value.second?.startLocation else { return }
                guard let endLocation = value.second?.location else { return }
                guard ((location.x-1)...(location.x+1)).contains(endLocation.x),
                      ((location.y-1)...(location.y+1)).contains(endLocation.y) else {
                    return
                }
                
                action(location)
            }
    }
}

extension View {
    func onClickGesture(
        count: Int,
        coordinateSpace: CoordinateSpace = .local,
        perform action: @escaping (CGPoint) -> Void
    ) -> some View {
        gesture(ClickGesture(count: count, coordinateSpace: coordinateSpace)
            .onEnded(perform: action)
        )
    }
    
    func onClickGesture(
        count: Int,
        perform action: @escaping (CGPoint) -> Void
    ) -> some View {
        onClickGesture(count: count, coordinateSpace: .local, perform: action)
    }
    
    func onClickGesture(
        perform action: @escaping (CGPoint) -> Void
    ) -> some View {
        onClickGesture(count: 1, coordinateSpace: .local, perform: action)
    }
}
```

---

### Previous Workaround

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56513942/how-to-detect-a-tap-gesture-location-in-swiftui) SO question linked in a comment, I adapted the UIKit solution suitable for macOS.

Apart from changing the types I added a computation to compute the position in the macOS coordinate system style. There is still an ugly force unwrap but I do not know enough AppKit to remove it safely.

You should use this modifier before other gestures modifiers if you want multiple simultaneous gestures on one view.

Currently the `CoordinateSpace` argument only works for `.local` and `.global` but is not implemented correctly for `.named(Hashable)`.

If you have solutions for some of those issues I'll update the answer.

Here is the code:

```swift
public extension View {
    func onTapWithLocation(count: Int = 1, coordinateSpace: CoordinateSpace = .local, _ tapHandler: @escaping (CGPoint) -> Void) -> some View {
        modifier(TapLocationViewModifier(tapHandler: tapHandler, coordinateSpace: coordinateSpace, count: count))
    }
}

fileprivate struct TapLocationViewModifier: ViewModifier {
    let tapHandler: (CGPoint) -> Void
    let coordinateSpace: CoordinateSpace
    let count: Int
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.overlay(
            TapLocationBackground(tapHandler: tapHandler, coordinateSpace: coordinateSpace, numberOfClicks: count)
        )
    }
}

fileprivate struct TapLocationBackground: NSViewRepresentable {
    let tapHandler: (CGPoint) -> Void
    let coordinateSpace: CoordinateSpace
    let numberOfClicks: Int
    
    func makeNSView(context: NSViewRepresentableContext<TapLocationBackground>) -> NSView {
        let v = NSView(frame: .zero)
        let gesture = NSClickGestureRecognizer(target: context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.tapped))
        gesture.numberOfClicksRequired = numberOfClicks
        v.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
        return v
    }
    
    final class Coordinator: NSObject {
        let tapHandler: (CGPoint) -> Void
        let coordinateSpace: CoordinateSpace
        
        init(handler: @escaping ((CGPoint) -> Void), coordinateSpace: CoordinateSpace) {
            self.tapHandler = handler
            self.coordinateSpace = coordinateSpace
        }
        
        @objc func tapped(gesture: NSClickGestureRecognizer) {
            let height = gesture.view!.bounds.height
            var point = coordinateSpace == .local
                ? gesture.location(in: gesture.view)
                : gesture.location(in: nil)
            point.y = height - point.y
            tapHandler(point)
        }
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> TapLocationBackground.Coordinator {
        Coordinator(handler: tapHandler, coordinateSpace: coordinateSpace)
    }
    
    func updateNSView(_: NSView, context _: NSViewRepresentableContext<TapLocationBackground>) { }
}
```