# Does anyone have MapKit+LongPress working?

Tags: swiftui, mapkit, gesture

I am trying to get SwiftUI + MapKit + LongPress gesture working. When I add the map within the `ContentView`, it works great. I then add the `.onLongPressGesture` modifier to the map, and the panning/zooming stops working. Long press works though.

The code I am working on:

```swift
Map(coordinateRegion: $region, interactionModes: .all, showsUserLocation: true)
  .onLongPressGesture {
    // How do I get the location (Lat/Long) I am pressed on?
    print("onLongPressGesture")
  }
```

Also, is there a way to get the lat/long from the long press gesture?

Looking to make it work using `SwiftUI` only, without wrapping `UIKit` within a `UIViewRepresentable`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't ask why but this seems to work:

```
    Map(coordinateRegion: $region, interactionModes: .all, showsUserLocation: true)
        .gesture(DragGesture())
        .onLongPressGesture {
            print("Here!")
        }
```

Comment: Based on ChrisR gesture I looked into using gesture I think this is the right way to do it

`Map(coordinateRegion: $region, interactionModes: .all, showsUserLocation: true)
                .gesture(DragGesture())
                .gesture(
                    LongPressGesture()                        
                        .onEnded { value in
                            print("LongPressGesture "+value.description)
                        }
                    )`

Still can not figure out how to get lat/long, Any Ideas?
I know you take the x,y of the screen and convert to lat/long

Comment: getting the tap/longpress location unfortunately is not that easy in SwiftUI ... start from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56513942/how-to-detect-a-tap-gesture-location-in-swiftui

Comment: Once you have the press location you can relate that you your currently shown coordinateRegion and recalculate into lat/lon.

Comment: btw: a much simpler approach would be to have some fixed circle or crosshairs in the center of the screen which sets a new pinned location on button press. btw2: SwiftUI's Map View is very very basic compared to UIKit.

Comment: For posterity - Paul Hudson shows how to get the tap (or long press) location in lat/long on [this page](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/integrating-mapkit-with-swiftui)

`    MapReader { proxy in`
`        Map()`
`            .onTapGesture { position in`
`                if let coordinate = proxy.convert(position, from: .local) {`
`                    print(coordinate)`
`                }`
`            }`
`    }`

Comment: When I do this, I don't get called till releasing the tap.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I was able to get the location of a LongPressGesture, while also preserving the functionality of the Map initializer's `selection` parameter (i.e. long pressing not allowed on existing map objects):

```swift
struct MapLongPressTestView: View {
    @State private var selectedMapItemTag: String? = nil
    private let randomCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: .random(in: -90...90), longitude: .random(in: -180...180))

    var body: some View {
        MapReader { proxy in
            Map(selection: $selectedMapItemTag) {
                // Your Annotations, Markers, Shapes, & other map content

                // Selectable Test Example
                Annotation(coordinate: randomCoordinate) {
                    Image(systemName: "water.waves")
                        .foregroundStyle(.orange)
                } label: {
                    Text("Water, most likely")
                }
                .tag("example")
            }
            .gesture(DragGesture())
            .gesture(
                LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 1, maximumDistance: 0)
                    .sequenced(before: SpatialTapGesture(coordinateSpace: .local))
                    .onEnded { value in
                        switch value {
                        case let .second(_, tapValue):
                            guard let point = tapValue?.location else {
                                print("Unable to retreive tap location from gesture data.")
                                return
                            }
                            
                            guard let coordinate = proxy.convert(point, from: .local) else {
                                print("Unable to convert local point to coordinate on map.")
                                return
                            }

                            print("Long press occured at: \(coordinate)")
                        default: return
                        }
                    }
            )
        }
        .onChange(of: selectedMapItemTag) {
            print(selectedMapItemTag.map { "\($0) is selected" } ?? "No selection")
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, here's an extension on the `Map` type to reduce boilerplate:

```swift
extension Map {
    func onLongPressGesture(minimumDuration: Double = 0, maximumDistance: CGFloat = 0, onTouchUp: @escaping (CGPoint) -> Void) -> some View {
        self
            .gesture(DragGesture())
            .gesture(
                LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: minimumDuration, maximumDistance: maximumDistance)
                    .sequenced(before: SpatialTapGesture(coordinateSpace: .local))
                    .onEnded { value in
                        switch value {
                        case .second(_, let tapValue):
                            guard let point = tapValue?.location else {
                                print("Unable to retreive tap location from gesture data.")
                                return
                            }

                            onTouchUp(point)
                        default: return
                        }
                    }
            )
    }
}
```

It would be used like so:

```swift
MapReader { proxy in
    Map(selection: $selectedMapItemTag) {
        // ...
    }
    .onLongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 1) { point in
        if let coordinate = proxy.convert(point, from: .local) {
            print("Long press occured at: \(coordinate)")
        }
    }
}
```

[`SpacialTapGesture`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/spatialtapgesture) is available from iOS 16+.

Answer (score 0):

Yep.

I wrapped `MKMapView` in `UIViewRepresentable` and added long press gesture recognizer in the delegate method like this:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
            // We need to update the region when the user changes it
            // otherwise when we zoom the mapview will return to its original region
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if self.longPress == nil {
                    let recognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.longPressGesture(recognizer:)))
                    mapView.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
                    self.longPress = recognizer
                }
                self.parent.region = mapView.region
            }
        }
```

Then

```
    @objc func longPressGesture(recognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        if let mapView = recognizer.view as? MKMapView {
            let touchPoint = recognizer.location(in: mapView)
            let touchMapCoordinate =  mapView.convert(touchPoint, toCoordinateFrom: mapView)
            
            // TODO: check if we already have this location and bail out
            if annotations.count > 0 {
                return
            }
            
            let annotation = Annotation(title: touchMapCoordinate.stringValue, coordinate: touchMapCoordinate)
            mapView.removeAnnotations(annotations.compactMap({ $0.pointAnnotation }))
            annotations.append(annotation)
            mapView.addAnnotation(annotation.pointAnnotation)
        }
    }
```

Using the code from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71698741/1320010

Answer (score 0):

To answer the last part of your question - Paul Hudson shows how to get the tap location in lat/long on [this page](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/integrating-mapkit-with-swiftui) [EDIT - doesn't seem to work for long press]

```
    MapReader { proxy in    
        Map()    
            .onTapGesture { position in    
                if let coordinate = proxy.convert(position, from: .local) {    
                    print(coordinate)    
                }    
            }    
    }
```