# SwiftUI coordinates of a double tap inside a View pre iOS 16

Tags: swiftui, uikit, uihostingcontroller

I need to locate the position of the last double tap within a large view, and I'm limited in what I can do to achieve this result as follows:

1. I can't use `DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)` simultaneously to a `TapGesture(count: 2)` because the drag gesture is needed for something else and can't be overridden.
2. I can't use `onTapGesture { location in` since the target iOS version is `iOS 15.0` in my project.
3. I can't use `Introspect` since the large view I'm talking about is a large `LazyHStack` and there is no knowledge of what kind of `UIView`s are being used under the hood to implement it. Also way too fragile, would like to avoid.

So apparently I'm kinda forced to use an `UIViewControllerRepresentable` hosting another SwiftUI view through an `UIHostingController`. Problem is, I'm unfamiliar with UIKit and integrating UIKit with SwiftUI and the other way around. Kinda never done it before.

Nevertheless, I came up with a solution that kinda does the job for small views, but has terrible performances (CPU spikes to 100%) when the inner view is large and updates, making my solution not viable at all in its current state (scales terribly).

This is what I came up with:

**TapReadingView:**

```
import SwiftUI

struct TapReadingView<Content>: View where Content: View {
    var lastTapLocation: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: Double.nan, y: Double.nan)
    private var content: (CGPoint) -> Content
    var intrinsicSizeDidChange: () -> Void
    
    init(intrinsicSizeDidChange: @escaping () -> Void, content: @escaping (CGPoint) -> Content) {
        self.intrinsicSizeDidChange = intrinsicSizeDidChange
        self.content = content
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        self.content(lastTapLocation)
            .background {
                GeometryReader { proxy in
                    Color.clear
                        .onAppear {
                            self.intrinsicSizeDidChange()
                        }
                        .onChange(of: proxy.size) { _ in
                            self.intrinsicSizeDidChange()
                        }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

**TapReadingVC**:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

class TapReadingVC<Content>: UIViewController where Content : View {
    var hostingController: UIHostingController<TapReadingView<Content>>
    var numberOfTaps: Int
    
    init(hostingController: UIHostingController<TapReadingView<Content>>, numberOfTaps: Int = 1) {
        self.numberOfTaps = numberOfTaps
        self.hostingController = hostingController
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    ///1. Add the hosted controller as a child to this VC
    ///2. Clear the background view of this VC and of the SwiftUI hosted view
    ///3. Specify constraints
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.hostingController.rootView.intrinsicSizeDidChange = { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            self.hostingController.view.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        }
        
        addChild(hostingController)
        view.addSubview(hostingController.view)
        hostingController.didMove(toParent: self)

        view.backgroundColor = .clear
        hostingController.view.backgroundColor = .clear
        
        view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        hostingController.view.backgroundColor = .clear

        hostingController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            hostingController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            hostingController.view.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor),
            hostingController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            hostingController.view.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor),
        ])
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        preferredContentSize = hostingController.view.intrinsicContentSize
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    }
    
    ///1. Remove all the gesture recognizers to the hosted view before detaching it
    ///2. Remove the hosted view's associated VC from this VC
    ///3. Replace the new hosted view's `intrinsicSizeDidChange` callback
    ///4. Attach a new `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the new SwiftUI hosted view
    ///5. Attach the new SwiftUI hosted view as a child to this VC
    ///6. Constraint the new SwiftUI view to the bounds of this VC's associated view
    ///
    ///**Parameters:**
    /// - `with`: The `UIHostingController` hosting the view that the current one needs to be replaced with
    /// - `target`: The object that will be notified of tap gestures
    /// - `action`: A selector to an `@objc` method that contains the logic to respond to taps
    func replaceHostedVC(with: UIHostingController<TapReadingView<Content>>, target: Any? = nil, action: Selector? = nil) {
        
        self.hostingController.view.gestureRecognizers?.forEach(
            self.hostingController.view.removeGestureRecognizer
        )
        
        self.hostingController.willMove(toParent: nil)
        self.hostingController.view.removeFromSuperview()
        self.hostingController.removeFromParent()
                
        with.view.backgroundColor = .clear
        with.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        with.rootView.intrinsicSizeDidChange = { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            self.hostingController.view.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        }
            
       let newGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(
            target: target,
            action: action
       )
    
       newGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = self.numberOfTaps
        
       with.view.addGestureRecognizer(newGestureRecognizer)
        
       self.addChild(with)
       self.view.addSubview(with.view)
       with.didMove(toParent: self)
                
       self.hostingController = with
       self.hostingController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

       NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
           hostingController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
           hostingController.view.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor),
           hostingController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
           hostingController.view.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor),
       ])

    }
}
```

**SpatialGestureCoordinator**:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

class SpatialGestureCoordinator<Content> where Content : View {
    private var hostedVC: UIHostingController<TapReadingView<Content>>? = nil
    private var content: (CGPoint) -> Content
    
    private var lastTapLocation: CGPoint = .zero {
        didSet {
            guard let hostedVC = self.hostedVC else { return }
            hostedVC.rootView.lastTapLocation = self.lastTapLocation
        }
    }
    
    init(content: @escaping (CGPoint) -> Content) {
        self.content = content
        self.hostedVC =
            UIHostingController(
                rootView:
                    TapReadingView { //IntrinsicSizeDiDChange
                    
                    } content: { lastTapLocation in
                        content(lastTapLocation)
                    }
            )
    }
    
    @objc func respondToTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        guard let hostedVC = self.hostedVC else { return }
        let location = sender.location(in: hostedVC.view)
        
        let state = sender.state
        
        switch state {
            case .ended:
                self.lastTapLocation = location
            default:
                break
        }
        
    }
    
    func getHostingController() -> UIHostingController<TapReadingView<Content>>? {
        return self.hostedVC
    }
    
    func setContainedView(_ content: @escaping (CGPoint) -> Content) {
        self.content = content
        self.hostedVC = UIHostingController(
            rootView:
                TapReadingView { //IntrinsicSizeDiDChange
                
                } content: { lastTapLocation in
                    content(lastTapLocation)
                }
        )
        
    }
}
```

**SpatialTapGestureView**:

````
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

///A view that allows the detection and location of tap gestures within the `Content` view.
///
///If not explicitly specified otherwise, this view will automatically expand its size to full width and height
///similarly to a `GeometryReader`. To prevent this from happening, specify `.fixedSize()`
///as a modifier for this view. This will cause the view to wrap its content. If the frame of the `Content` view changes
///the underlying `UIViewController` invalidates the `UIHostingController`'s `intrinsicContentSize` and
///resizes accordingly to allow a correct tap detection within all the new frame.
///
///In this implementation, wrapping a `ScrollView` within a `SpatialTapGestureView` will break scroll in
///the `ScrollView`, therefore if you want to use these two `View`s in association, it is recommended to let `ScrollView`
///be the outer, wrapper `View`, and `SpatialTapGestureView` as the inner `View`. Here is an example of usage:
///
///```
///    ScrollView(.horizontal) {
///         SpatialTapGestureView { tl in
///             LazyHStack(spacing: 0) {
///                 ForEach(0..<10) { _ in
///                     Rectangle()
///                         .fill(Color.random())
///                         .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
///                         .overlay {
///                             Text("\(tl.x, specifier: "%.1f"), \(tl.y, specifier: "%.1f")")
///                                 .font(.headline)
///                         }
///                 }
///             }
///         }
///         .fixedSize()
///     }
///```
///
/// **Parameters**
/// - `numberOfTaps`: the number of taps required to fire the gesture event
/// - `Content`: the SwiftUI view that needs to track the tap gesture
///
struct SpatialTapGestureView<Content>: UIViewControllerRepresentable where Content : View {
    
    private var content: (CGPoint) -> Content
    private var numberOfTaps: Int
    
    init(numberOfTaps: Int = 1, content: @escaping (CGPoint) -> Content) {
        self.content = content
        self.numberOfTaps = numberOfTaps
    }
    
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> SpatialGestureCoordinator<Content> {
        return SpatialGestureCoordinator<Content>(content: self.content)
    }
    
    ///1. Initialize the view controller with the hosted view
    ///2. Attach an initial gesture recognizer to the SwiftUI hosted view
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
        guard let hostedVC = context.coordinator.getHostingController() else {
            fatalError("Could not initialize hosted view")
        }
                        
        let wrappingViewController = TapReadingVC<Content>(
            hostingController: hostedVC,
            numberOfTaps: self.numberOfTaps
        )
        
        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(
            target: self, action: #selector(context.coordinator.respondToTap)
        )
        
        tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = self.numberOfTaps
        hostedVC.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
        
        return wrappingViewController
    }
    
    ///1. Update the coordinator's contained view
    ///2. Call the ViewController's content update method
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {

        context.coordinator.setContainedView(self.content)
        
        guard let hostedVC = context.coordinator.getHostingController() else { return }
        guard let vc = (uiViewController as? TapReadingVC<Content>) else {
            fatalError("Could not convert VC to TapReadingVC")
        }
                
        vc.replaceHostedVC(
            with: hostedVC,
            target: context.coordinator,
            action: #selector(context.coordinator.respondToTap(_:))
        )
    }

}
````

This is an usage example that reproduces the bad performance issues:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var rectanglesHeight: CGFloat = 100.0
    @State private var lastTapLocation: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: Double.nan, y: Double.nan)
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                SpatialTapGestureView { tl in
                    LazyHStack(spacing: 0) {
                        ForEach(0..<100) { _ in
                            Rectangle()
                                .fill(Color.random())
                                .frame(width: 100, height: self.rectanglesHeight)
                                .overlay {
                                    Text("\(self.lastTapLocation.x, specifier: "%.1f"), \(self.lastTapLocation.y, specifier: "%.1f")")
                                        .font(.headline)
                                }
                                .onChange(of: tl, perform: { nextTL in
                                    guard nextTL.isFinite() else { return }
                                    self.lastTapLocation = nextTL
                                })
                        }
                    }
                }
                .fixedSize()
            }
            
            Slider(
                value: self.$rectanglesHeight,
                in: 50...UIScreen.main.bounds.height/3,
                step: 1
            )
            
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}


extension CGPoint {
    func isFinite() -> Bool {
        return self.x.isFinite && self.y.isFinite
    }
}
```

Can the performance issues be solved or is it inherent to the integration I'm trying? What alternatives do I have or how can I improve?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect a tap gesture location in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56513942/how-to-detect-a-tap-gesture-location-in-swiftui)

Comment: @Yrp: I already found that post and Yiannis' answer helped me solving. At the same time, I'd like to understand what was wrong with my approach for learning purposes.