# How to set Keyboard type of TextField in SwiftUI?

Tags: keyboard, swiftui, ios13

I can't seem to find any information or figure out how to set the keyboard type on a TextField for SwiftUI.
It would also be nice to be able to enable the secure text property, to hide passwords etc.

This post shows how to "wrap" a UITextField, but I'd rather not use any UI-controls if I don't have to.
[How to make TextField become first responder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56507839/how-to-make-textfield-become-first-responder)

Anyone have any ideas how this can be done without wrapping an old school UI control?

Comment: Alright, well it hasn't even been out a week, Apple will hopefully make some things like that a bit easier in the future. Hard when you have a deadline for shortly after iOS13 will be released and you don't know if simple things like selecting keyboard type will be available upon release. Thanks for the answer and clarification @MatteoPacini

Answer (score 119, accepted):

To create a field where you can enter secure text you can use `SecureField($password)`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/securefield

If you want to set the `contentType` of an textField to eg. `.oneTimeCode` you can do it like this. Also works with `keyboardType`

```
TextField($code)
    .textContentType(.oneTimeCode)
    .keyboardType(.numberPad)
```

Comment: This looks like more legit answer.

Comment: Thanks! That worked great for the password, but any way to set the keyboard type for a TextView? I tried setting the textContentType to .emailAddress but it didn't change to the email keyboard.

Comment: @AaronBertsch Setting the contentType does not change the keyboard. It seems to be a missing feature. For the time being, you need to use UITextField if you must select a different keyboard. I have created a bug report with Apple, I suggest you do the same, the more the merrier.

Comment: A new modifier in beta5 let you change the keyboard type, posted a new answer below.

Comment: Can we set the custom inputView on SwiftUI?

Answer (score 25):

We no longer need to use hacks. Beta 5 has brought a new modifier to set the keyboard type. For example, to use a number pad:

```swift
.keyboardType(.numberPad)
```

There's also `autocapitalization()` and an EnvironmentValue `disableAutocorrection`.

Comment: So there's yet a problem if you're using a NumberFormatter. If you use the default keyboard, the return key does cause the value to propagate to the bound value. If you use a decimal keyboard, as makes sense for fields with an attached NumberFormatter, there *is* no return key, and in fact the entered value never gets propagated to the bound value.

Answer (score 13):

To set `TextField's` keyboard type you need to add modifier `.keyboardType()`.

```
TextField(placeHolder, text: "your text here")
    .keyboardType(.numberPad)
```

Answer (score 4):

Set `.keyboardType(.numberPad)` on the TextField. Simple!

Answer (score 3):

The following wraps a `UITextField` class called `UIKitTextField` using `UIViewRepresentable`. The keyboard type is set to `.decimalPad` but could be set to any valid keyboard type.

```
//  UIKitTextField.swift

import UIKit

class UIKitTextField: UITextField, UITextFieldDelegate {

  required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    delegate = self
  }

  required override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    delegate = self
    self.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .vertical)
  }
}
```

In the `ContentView.Swift` I created two `TextFields`. The first is the wrapped `UIKit` `UITextField` and the second is the SwiftUI `TextField`. The data binding is the same so each will display the same text as it is entered.

```
// ContentView.Swift

import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct MyTextField : UIViewRepresentable {

  @Binding var myText: String

  func makeCoordinator() -> MyTextField.Coordinator {
    return Coordinator(text: $myText)
  }

  class Coordinator: NSObject {
    @Binding var text: String
    init(text: Binding<String>) {
      $text = text
    }

    @objc func textFieldEditingChanged(_ sender: UIKitTextField) {
      self.text = sender.text ?? ""
    }
  }

  func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIKitTextField {

    let myTextField = UIKitTextField(frame: .zero)

    myTextField.addTarget(context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.textFieldEditingChanged(_:)), for: .editingChanged)

    myTextField.text = self.myText
    myTextField.placeholder = "placeholder"
    myTextField.borderStyle = .roundedRect
    myTextField.keyboardType = .decimalPad

    return myTextField
  }

  func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIKitTextField,
                    context: Context) {
    uiView.text = self.myText
  }

}


struct MyTextFieldView: View {
  @State var myText: String = "Test"
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      MyTextField(myText: $myText)
        .padding()
      TextField($myText)
        .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
        .padding()
    }
  }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    Group{
      MyTextFieldView().previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)
      MyTextFieldView().previewDevice("iPhone Xs")
    }
  }
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 3):

**Xcode 13** - **iOS & WatchOS App**

if you are making a WatchOS app, at the same time as an iOS app you need to add condition for OS check like in code below

```
           #if os(iOS)
            TextField(placeHolder, text: $text)
                .keyboardType(.numbersAndPunctuation)
            #endif
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm the dev that answered that post - there's no official way to do so
>   at the moment. Your best bet at the moment is to wrap UITextField – Matteo Pacini

That sums it up, guess we are stuck with wrapping UITextField for now.

Comment: @Viktor's answer is correct - I can't find that method on my Xcode :sadface:, I had to look it up in the online documentation. The joys of beta Xcode.

Answer (score -2):

This works for me:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

class UIKitTextField: UITextField, UITextFieldDelegate {

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        delegate = self
    }

    required override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        delegate = self
        self.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .vertical)
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

}

struct UBSTextField : UIViewRepresentable {

    @Binding var myText: String
    let placeHolderText: String

    func makeCoordinator() -> UBSTextField.Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(text: $myText)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject {
        var textBinding: Binding<String>
        init(text: Binding<String>) {
            self.textBinding = text
        }

        @objc func textFieldEditingChanged(_ sender: UIKitTextField) {
            self.textBinding.wrappedValue = sender.text ?? ""
        }
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIKitTextField {

        let textField = UIKitTextField(frame: .zero)

        textField.addTarget(context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.textFieldEditingChanged(_:)), for: .editingChanged)

        textField.text = self.myText
        textField.placeholder = self.placeHolderText
        textField.borderStyle = .none
        textField.keyboardType = .asciiCapable
        textField.returnKeyType = .done
        textField.autocapitalizationType = .words
        textField.clearButtonMode = .whileEditing

        return textField
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIKitTextField,
                      context: Context) {
        uiView.text = self.myText
    }
}
```