# SwiftUI rename SideBar item

Tags: swiftui

I'm using SwiftUI and create a SlideMenu, I want to rename my menu item. I do it by change Text to TextField but the TextField disabled by default. What wrong with TextField, I unable to click on it or is there any way to rename without swap Text <-> TextField?

[image: SlideMenu]

```
    struct CellView: View {
    @State private var isRename = false
    @State private var newName: String = ""
    var menuItem: MenuItem
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: "folder")
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            if isRename {
                TextField(menuItem.name ?? "Unknow name", text: $newName)
            }else {
                Text(menuItem.name ?? "Unknow name")
            }
            Spacer()
        }        
        .contextMenu {
            Button(action: {
                isRename = true
            }) {
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "pencil")
                        .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                    Text("Rename")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Update: It actually can click on it and edit but very hard. I think this is a beta bug and Apple will fix it in the feature.

Comment: 9 months later, I wonder if you have solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is disabled (as tested provided code), you just see placeholder and TextField is not in focus by default.

So here is possible solution (based on `CustomTextField` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61121199/12299030))

```
    if isRename {
         CustomTextField(text: $newName,
                nextResponder: .constant(nil),
                isResponder: .constant(true),
                isSecured: false,
                keyboard: .default)
    }else {
        Text(menuItem.name ?? "Unknow name")
    }
    Spacer()
}        
.contextMenu {
    Button(action: {
        newName = menuItem.name ?? "Unknown name"
        isRename = true
    }) {
```

*Note: it is not shown what is `MenuItem` but consider possibility to bind text field directly to `menuItem.name`*

Comment: Thank you for your help, It can click but very hard, I think this is a bug from the beta version. BTW I write this app for Mac but your suggestions really help. If Apple does not fix it in October I will try to use NSTextField.

Answer (score 0):

With iOS 16, there's a built-in `RenameButton` view and a `.renameAction{}` modifier:

```
RenameButton()
.renameAction {
   //add action here
 }
```