# SwiftUI - State change in UITextField causes the frameWidth to grow uncontrolled and ignore bounds/frame

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uikit, swiftui, uiviewrepresentable

I am using SwiftUI and bridge to UITextField (I need to assign firstResponder). I use the code from here: [SwiftUI: How to make TextField become first responder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56507839/swiftui-how-to-make-textfield-become-first-responder/56508132#56508132)

The following code updates my @Binding var. This of course is intended behavior. The problem is that this causes the textField to ignore the frame/ bounds. It just expands and pushes other elements out of the view. Other parts of the view are also reliant on the @State.

```
func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField) {
            text = textField.text ?? ""
}
```

How can I update the @State and still keep the textField in the frame?

Answer (score 128, accepted):

You need to decrease priority of content resistance in `makeUIView` (so content would not push external layout set in SwiftUI) like below

```
func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<MyField>) -> UITextField {
    let field = UITextField(frame: .zero)
    field.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
    ...
```

Comment: I have been struggling with this for hours. Finally figured out the right incantation to use with Stackoverflow and this question, along with your gloriously simple answer, appeared. THANK YOU so much!

Comment: using this I occasionally see the cursor disappear when setting focus to another textField.  Even when that new textField has focus.