# Label increase the length of stack view from both size

Tags: swift, stackview

I have a label in a stack view, everything is defined Programmatically, but when the size of this label is increase, the size of the entire stack view increase from left and right side. Could you tell me how the configuration should looks like to avoid it?
Many thanks

Comment: try to set  height constraint  for stack view

Comment: I can't do that, I want something like adjustFontSizeToFitrWidth but for cutting label with dots ...

Comment: you can set number of lines to your label to avoid cutting text

Comment: Actually I want to cutting, not changing the font size, without set height or width constraints for slackview

Comment: Please look this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59192194/swiftui-state-change-in-uitextfield-causes-the-framewidth-to-grow-uncontrolled/59193838#59193838) - topic is different but the solution is the same.