# I wrap UITextfield using UIViewRepresentable in SwiftUI, but I cannot set the width

Tags: swiftui, textfield

Updated: I found the answer and fix this issue: (FYI: [SwiftUI - State change in UITextField causes the frameWidth to grow uncontrolled and ignore bounds/frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59192194/swiftui-state-change-in-uitextfield-causes-the-framewidth-to-grow-uncontrolled/59193838#59193838))

```
func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<MyField>) -> UITextField {
    let field = UITextField(frame: .zero)
    field.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
```

When I input more and more text in it, the text field will grow wider and wider, even if set frame width.

```
public struct FoolTextField: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var text: String
    private let textField = UITextField(frame: .zero)

    public init(_ placeholder: String, text: Binding<String>) {
        _text = text
        textField.text = text.wrappedValue
        textField.placeholder = placeholder
        textField.borderStyle = .none
        textField.clearButtonMode = .whileEditing
        textField.returnKeyType = .done
    }
    ...
}


FoolTextField("placeholder", text: $text).frame(width: 200)
```

Comment: I think you need to pass the width manually and apply it to the `UITextField`.

Comment: @krjw it's not useful.

Comment: @krjw issue fixed, thanks anyway.

Comment: Great! How did you fix it if I may ask?

Comment: @krjw Original post has been updated including fixing.