# A text field wrapped with UIKit protrudes from the area when typing a lot of text

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit, uitextfield

Creating a text field in SwiftUI using UI kit.
However, the text is displayed as overflowing.
What should I add to the custom?

[image]
Originally, I want to make this red area a text field area.

[image]

```
struct FirstResponderTextField: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var text: String
    let placeholder: String
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {

        @Binding var text: String
        var becameFirstResponder = false
        init(text: Binding<String>) {
            self ._text = text
        }
        func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField) {
            text = textField.text ?? ""
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(text: $text)

    }
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> some UIView {
        let textField = UITextField()
        textField.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 40, weight: .bold).rounded()
        textField.delegate = context.coordinator
        textField.placeholder = placeholder
        return textField
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {
        if !context.coordinator.becameFirstResponder {
            uiView.becomeFirstResponder()
            context.coordinator.becameFirstResponder = true
        }
    }
}
extension UIFont {
    func rounded() -> UIFont {
        if let descriptor = self.fontDescriptor.withDesign(.rounded) {
            let fontSize = self.pointSize
            return UIFont(descriptor: descriptor, size: fontSize)
        } else {
            return self
        }
    }
}
```

I'm new to SwiftUI and would appreciate any comments or feedback.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/59193838/12299030?

Comment: Thanks for the perfect answer!
Now I can finish my first product in my life!!!
I'm glad you gave me a great answer!