# Text goes outside UITextField when filled with text in Swift

Tags: swiftui, uikit, swift5

I am using this UITextField in SwiftUI because there seems to be no way to deal with firstResponder before iOS 15 where focused was introduced. But the problem I am having has to do with the text inside the UITextField. When I totally fill the field with text, the first letters start showing up on the left side of the field (outside the field).
Any idea how to prevent this?
There are two commented lines in makeUIView that I also tried including but with no luck.

```
MyCustomTextField(text: self.$word,
                  placeholderText: "text",
                  width: -20-2*0.1*geo.size.height+geo.size.width,
                  height: 0.1*geo.size.height
                  )
.frame(width: -20-2*0.1*geo.size.height+geo.size.width, height: 0.1*geo.size.height)


struct MyCustomTextField: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var text: String
    var placeholderText: String
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
        @Binding var text: String
        var didBecomeFirstResponder = false

        init(text: Binding<String>) {
            _text = text
        }

        func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField) {
            text = textField.text ?? ""
        }
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextField {
        let textField = UITextField(frame: .zero)
        //textField.layer.masksToBounds = true
        //textField.clipsToBounds = true

        textField.delegate = context.coordinator
        textField.textColor = .black
        textField.placeholder = self.placeholderText
        textField.textAlignment = .center
        return textField
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(text: $text)
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<MyCustomTextField>) {
        uiView.text = text
        uiView.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 20)
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/59193838/12299030?

Comment: Yes it solved it, thank you.