# How to make first responder in SwiftUI macOS

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, swiftui

I'm trying to make my textField (`NSViewRepresentable` wrapped `NSTextField`) the first responder when it appears. I have tested many answers in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56507839/swiftui-how-to-make-textfield-become-first-responder), but they are either not working:

```swift
func updateNSView(_ nsView: MyField, context: Context) {
  if some_condition {
    print(nsViews.becomeFirstResponder()) // returns false
    negate_condition()
  }
  ...
}
```

Or it crashes with logs `(=== AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute 43 ===)`:

```swift
func updateNSView(_ nsViews: MyField, context: Context) {
  if some_condition {
    Window.thisWindow?.makeFirstResponder(nsViews)
    negate_condition()
  }
  ...
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is:

```swift
@State var fieldActive: Bool
body: some View {
  MyField(...).onAppear { /*makeFirstResponder if fieldActive == true*/ }
}
```

Can someone please help me on this? Thank you very much!

Comment: Does `MyField` inherit from `NSTextField` or aggregate it? Would you provide code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your `MyField` is a `NSTextField` the following works. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / macOS 10.15.4

```
  func makeNSView(context: Context) -> MyField {
    let view = MyField()

    // ... other properties set up here

    // wait for next cycle, so field be already in window
    DispatchQueue.main.async { 
        view.window?.makeFirstResponder(view)
    }
    return view
  }
```

Comment: This approach is a working approach. So I will pick yours as the valid answer. I found a different approach, and I will post it down below. Thank you for answering

Answer (score 2):

@Asperi provided a valid approach, I have found another path to the answer. I used the [SwiftUI-Introspect library](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect) to complete the work with SwiftUI TextField (not wrapped NSTextField), here is the code:

```swift
struct SearchBar {
  @Binding var shouldActivate: Bool
  var body: some View {
    TextField("", text: text)
      .textFieldStyle(PlainTextFieldStyle())
      .introspectTextField { textField in 
          if self.shouldActivate {
              textField.becomeFirstResponder()
              self.shouldActivate = false
          }
          textField.focusRingType = .none
      }
}
```