# How do I get with SWIFTUI the textField as firstResponder like with Swift: textField.becomesFirstResponder

Tags: swiftui, textfield, becomefirstresponder

I have a textField in a SwiftUI file and want this fiel duo become the first responder and the keyboard should show up. In Swift I would simply do: textField.becomesFirstResponder().
Does anyone Has an idea how to do that in SwiftUI?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56507839/swiftui-how-to-make-textfield-become-first-responder

Comment: uups, thx, but very complicated...

Comment: This can be done easily in iOS 15, take a look at **[this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59059359/5623035)**

Answer (score 0):

for a simpler solution, instead of writing a custom textfield you can use this library, https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect:

```
TextField("placeholder", text: $someText).introspectTextField { textField in textField.becomeFirstResponder() }
```