# SwiftUI - making a textfield inside a view be the first responder on touch to that view

Tags: swiftui

On a view I have something like this:

```
TextFieldUsername()
```

this shows something like

[image]

So, this view shows an icon and the textfield username.

Below that, I have another one for the password.

Making that username field in focus is unnecessarily hard. The textfield is not small, but making the username field to focus is a matter of tapping on the exact position and perhaps you have to tap 2 or 3 times to make it happen.

I would like to make the whole `TextFieldUsername()` tappable or to increase the hit area of that textfield. I would like better to make the whole thing tappable and once tapped, make its textfield in focus.

This is TextFieldUsername

```
struct TextFieldUsername: View {
  
  @State var username:String
 

  var body: some View {
    
    HStack {
      Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle")
        .renderingMode(.template)
        .foregroundColor(.black)
        .opacity(0.3)
        .fixedSize()

      TextField(TextFieldUsernameStrings.username, text: $username)
        .textFieldStyle(PlainTextFieldStyle())
        .textContentType(.username)
        .autocapitalization(.none)
      
    }
  }
}
```

Is that possible in SwiftUI without using any external library like introspect?

Comment: Use UIKit representable for such things.

Comment: If I just knew how...

Comment: Can you show the code of your textfield and the view it is in.

Comment: yes. I have added it to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a custom `TextField` like the one from [Matteo Pacini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56507839/swiftui-how-to-make-textfield-become-first-responder)

you can do something like this:

```
struct CustomTextField1: UIViewRepresentable {
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
        @Binding var text: String
        var didBecomeFirstResponder = false
        init(text: Binding<String>) {
            _text = text
        }
        func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField) {
            text = textField.text ?? ""
        }
    }
    @Binding var text: String
    var isFirstResponder: Bool = false
    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<CustomTextField1>) -> UITextField {
        let textField = UITextField(frame: .zero)
        textField.delegate = context.coordinator
        return textField
    }
    func makeCoordinator() -> CustomTextField1.Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(text: $text)
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context:     UIViewRepresentableContext<CustomTextField1>) {
        uiView.text = text
        if isFirstResponder && !context.coordinator.didBecomeFirstResponder  {
            uiView.becomeFirstResponder()
            context.coordinator.didBecomeFirstResponder = true
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView : View {
    @State var text: String = ""
    @State var isEditing = false
    var body: some View {
        CustomTextField1(text: $text, isFirstResponder: isEditing)
            .frame(width: 300, height: 50)
            .background(Color.red)
            .onTapGesture {
                isEditing.toggle()
            }
    }
}
```

It's a bit complex, but should get the work done. As for a pure `SwiftUI` answer, it's currently unavailable.