# How to know when a SecureTextField in SwiftUI has gained focus or lost focus?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I want to know, how can we detect if a SecureTextField has lost focus or gained one.

Currently I am using tap gesture to check if focus is gained and change border color accordingly, but sometimes color changes but editing does not start.

```
SecureField("Password", text: $viewModel.password) {
                        passwordEditingState = .ended
                        focusedTextField = nil
                    }
                    .onTapGesture {
                        focusedTextField = TextFields.password.rawValue
                    }
                    .padding(20)
                    .background(Color.systemDefaultSecondary)
                    .cornerRadius(16.0)
                    .disableAutocorrection(true)
                    .autocapitalization(.none)
                    .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16).stroke(isSelected ? Color.green : Color.gray, lineWidth: 1))
```

One thing to consider that my app has minimum target of 14.1 so I need a solution based upon that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI: How to make TextField become first responder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56507839/swiftui-how-to-make-textfield-become-first-responder)

Comment: You can listen to the `isFirstResponder` property

Answer (score 4):

You can use `focused` modifier with `FocusState`, like below.

Demo prepared & tested with Xcode 13 / iOS 15.

*Note: you need Simulator or real device - it does not work in Preview*

[image: demo]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @FocusState var isInFocus: Bool
    @State private var text: String = "password"

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if isInFocus {
                Text("Field is in focus!")
            }
            SecureField("Password", text: $text)
                .focused($isInFocus)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is a iOS 15 feature and my app has the minimum target of 14.1. Could you help in that?

Comment: I faced the same issue. I found that listening for keyboard updates in a viewModel as a proxy for textfield focusing was a fair solution. may not apply in your case ...