# Swiftui is cursor on SecureField

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to get whether the cursor is inside the `SecureField`. If we're using `TextField`, we can achieve that by using `onEditingChange`, and we're good to go, but this isn't an option in `SecureField`, any solutions?

Notes:

1. I don't want to use `onTapGesture` since there are other ways to gain focus other than taping on the field
2. I don't want to use `@FocusState` since I'm building for ios versions less than 15

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/68608720/12299030?

Comment: @Asperi, yes, but I'm keeping this approach for the end since it's only available for ios 15