# Setting TextField /TextEditor as the first responder upon appearing SwifUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, textfield, text-editor

I've got a SwiftUI `TextEditor` that appears once a button is pressed. What I can't figure out is, how to make the `TextEditor` the first responder when it appears.

What I've tried is adding a `.focused` modifier to the `TextEditor` and then setting the focused Bool value to `true` inside `.onAppear`. But still the keyboard only shows up when its pressed.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var showTextField : Bool = false
    @State private var currentEditText : String = "Some text"
    @FocusState private var editTextFieldFocus: Bool
    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                showTextField.toggle()
            } label: {
                Text("Show Text Field")
            }

            Text("Hello, world!")
                .padding()
            if showTextField{
                TextEditor(text: $currentEditText)
                    .focused($editTextFieldFocus)
                    .onAppear {
                        editTextFieldFocus = true
                    }
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI: How to make TextField become first responder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56507839/swiftui-how-to-make-textfield-become-first-responder)

Comment: My question is slightly different as the text field is hidden initially. I have already tried what is suggested in that question and it doesn't work in this situation.

Comment: The problem was that the `editTextFieldFocus` is toggled before the `TextField` shows up. I just set `editTextFieldFocus ` to true inside `async` and it works as expected.