# How to reproduce the height/stacking effect with a ZStack in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I would like to reproduce inside a ZStack the height effect that you see when a modal is presented in iOS 13:

The background is slightly transparent and becomes greyish with a blur effect.

The idea would be to create a view that seems to be floating above the elements below inside a ZStack.

Comment: Could you provide some picture with what you want to achieve

Comment: something like the Music player when the iPhone's screen is locked

Comment: Something like this ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/56496896/10208552

Comment: exactly like a UIContextMenuInteraction...

Comment: @MycroftCanner Hi, was my answer below helpful to you? If so, feel free to accept it so that other users that come across this question know what answer worked for you. If not, let me know in the answer's comments what the problem is, or post your own solution if you found one that answers your question better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a `ZStack` with a view that is conditionally displayed depending on a `@State` variable. The variable will also determine the `.blur` amount on the underlying view and whether or not a transparent gray view is displayed in between (which makes the background look grayed out). I made an example to illustrate:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var modalIsPresented = false
    @State var alertIsPresented = false
    @State var customAlertIsPresented = false
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Text("Test!!!")

            VStack {
                Spacer()
                Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet")
                Spacer()
                Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet")
                Image(systemName: "star")
                Button(action: {
                    self.modalIsPresented = true
                }) {
                    Text("Present an actual modal")
                }
                Button(action: {
                    self.alertIsPresented = true
                }) {
                    Text("Present an actual alert")
                }
                Button(action: {
                    withAnimation {
                        self.customAlertIsPresented = true
                    }
                }) {
                    Text("Present your custom alert")
                }
            }
            .blur(radius: self.customAlertIsPresented ? 3 : 0)
            .animation(.easeOut)
            if customAlertIsPresented {
                Rectangle()
                    .background(Color.black)
                    .opacity(0.3)
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    .animation(.easeIn)
            }
            if customAlertIsPresented {
                CustomAlert(isPresented: $customAlertIsPresented).frame(width: 300)
                    .background(Color.white)
                    .animation(.easeIn)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .shadow(radius: 10)
            }
        }.sheet(isPresented: $modalIsPresented) {
            Text("This is what an actual modal looks like")
        }.alert(isPresented: $alertIsPresented) {
            Alert(title: Text("This is what an alert looks like"))
        }
    }
}

struct CustomAlert: View {
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("This is my custom alert").padding()
            Divider()
            Button(action: {
                self.isPresented = false
            }) {
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Text("Dismiss")
                    Spacer()
                }
            }.padding([.top, .bottom], 10)
        }
    }
}
```

I added some animations to make the transition smoother. You can adjust things like the `.blur`, `.opacity`, and various `.animation`s to customize it took look just the way you want. Here's what my example looks like:

[image: Prior to showing alert][image: After showing the alert]