# Show loading image until response

Tags: swiftui, alamofire

I'm sending via AlamoFire an audio file to a REST API and get a JSON response. Meanwhile I would like to display a loading image (e.g. animated circle) until I receive the response. My current solution is so far:

```
let voiceData = try? Data(contentsOf: audioRecorder.url)
let uploadUrl = "<server ip>"
    
AF.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
   multipartFormData.append(voiceData!, withName: "file", fileName: "recording.m4a", mimeType: "audio/mpeg")
},
to: uploadUrl, method: .post)
.responseJSON { resp in
    print(resp)
}
```

Now how can I show the loading image in my SwiftUI View?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/58959008/12299030?

Comment: This might help you: [SwiftUI Network Image show different views on loading and error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64416344/8697793) and [How can I load an UIImage into a SwiftUI Image asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65778418/8697793)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about AlamoFire, but in order to do 2 things in parallel, you must use async methods, so this is what you could do (in JavaScript):

```
document.querySelector("#getInfoBtn").addEventListener('click',() => {
    toggleInfoBtnSpinner()
    setTimeout(AFUpload, 10)
});

let toggleInfoBtnSpinner = () => {
    const btn = document.querySelector("#getInfoBtn")
    const spinner = btn.querySelector("#infoSpinner")

    if (spinner == null) {
        btn.innerHTML = `<span id="infoSpinner" class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>Search`
    } else {
        spinner.remove()
        btn.innerHTML = `Search`
    }
    btn.disabled = !btn.disabled
}
```

This will set the spinner start and then, you'll execute your `AFUpload` function after 10 ms as an async function and you can trigger something rom that function to let the system know it finished