# View Modifier messing with animations

Tags: animation, swiftui, binding, viewmodifier

I've been looking to add a loading indicator to my project, and found a really cool animation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56496638/activity-indicator-in-swiftui). To make it easier to use, I wanted to incorporate it into a view modifier to put it on top of the current view. However, when I do so, it doesn't animate when I first press the button. I have played around with it a little, and my hypothesis is that the View Modifier doesn't pass the initial `isAnimating = false`, so only passes it `isAnimating = true` when the button is pressed. Because the `ArcsAnimationView` doesn't get the false value initially, it doesn't actually animate anything and just shows the static arcs. However, if I press the button a second time afterwards, it seems to be initialized and the view properly animates as desired.

Is there a better way to structure my code to avoid this issue? Am I missing something key? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Below is the complete code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ArcsAnimationView: View {
    @Binding var isAnimating: Bool
    let count: UInt = 4
    let width: CGFloat = 5
    let spacing: CGFloat = 2
    
    init(isAnimating: Binding<Bool>) {
        self._isAnimating = isAnimating
    }

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ForEach(0..<Int(count)) { index in
                item(forIndex: index, in: geometry.size)
// the rotation below is what is animated ... 
// I think the problem is that it just starts at .degrees(360), instead of
// .degrees(0) as expected, where it is then animated to .degrees(360)
                    .rotationEffect(isAnimating ? .degrees(360) : .degrees(0))
                    .animation(
                        Animation.default
                            .speed(Double.random(in: 0.05...0.25))
                            .repeatCount(isAnimating ? .max : 1, autoreverses: false)
                        , value: isAnimating
                    )
                    .foregroundColor(Color(hex: AppColors.darkBlue1.rawValue))
            }
        }
       
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        
    }

    private func item(forIndex index: Int, in geometrySize: CGSize) -> some View {
        Group { () -> Path in
            var p = Path()
            p.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: geometrySize.width/2, y: geometrySize.height/2),
                     radius: geometrySize.width/2 - width/2 - CGFloat(index) * (width + spacing),
                     startAngle: .degrees(0),
                     endAngle: .degrees(Double(Int.random(in: 120...300))),
                     clockwise: true)
            return p.strokedPath(.init(lineWidth: width))
        }
        .frame(width: geometrySize.width, height: geometrySize.height)
    }
}


struct ArcsAnimationModifier: ViewModifier {
    @Binding var isAnimating: Bool
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        ZStack {
            if isAnimating {
                ArcsAnimationView(isAnimating: _isAnimating)
                    .frame(width: 150)
            }
            content
                .disabled(isAnimating)
        }       
    }
}

extension View {
    func loadingAnimation(isAnimating: Binding<Bool>) -> some View {
        self.modifier(ArcsAnimationModifier(isAnimating: isAnimating))
    }
}
```

Here is where I actually call the function:

```
struct AnimationView: View {
    
    @State var isAnimating = false

    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
        Button(action: {
            self.isAnimating = true
            
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 4) {
                self.isAnimating = false
            }
        }, label: {
            Text("show animation")
        })  
        }
        .loadingAnimation(isAnimating: $isAnimating)
        
    }
}
```

Note: I am fairly certain the issue is with View Modifier since if I call `ArcsAnimationView` as a regular view in `AnimationView`, it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I get there to see some implementation, but I think others would prefer a simple base to start from.
here my 2 cents to show how to write an AnimatableModifier that can be used on multiple objects cleaning up ".animation" in code.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var hideWhilelUpdating = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
    Image(systemName: "tshirt.fill")
        .modifier(SmoothHideAndShow(hide: hideWhilelUpdating))

        Text("Some contents to show...")
            .modifier(SmoothHideAndShow(hide: hideWhilelUpdating))

        Button( "hide and show smootly") {
            hideWhilelUpdating.toggle()
        }
        .padding(60)
    }
}


struct SmoothHideAndShow: AnimatableModifier {
    var hide: Bool

    var animatableData: CGFloat {
        get { CGFloat(hide ? 0 : 1) }
        set { hide = newValue == 0 }
    }

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
        .opacity(hide  ? 0.2 : 1)
            .animation(.easeIn(duration: 1), value: hide)

    }
}
```

when pressing button, our bool will trigger animation that fades in and out our text.
I use it during network calls (omitted for clarity... and replaced with button) to hide values under remote update. When network returns, I toggle boolean.